# Please inverse the community user's duplicate listing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions

Currently when a question is closed as a dupe, you'll see what question(s) it is a possible duplicate of.

But what about the opposite?

Since there are many occasions that duplicate questions can contain information that might be vital to some user. So to see other questions that are a duplicate of the one the user is browsing can be very helpful for those that need more information that might be in those other questions.

It could even be a portal. Since the duplicate question has the "root" question linked, and when you click on that you both get more information and other questions that have been voted duplicates.

What do you think?

Comment: This could be useful to get a sense of which questions are frequently asked/duplicated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes!

One useful side-effect of this would be to stop people (accidently) voting-to-close the wrong part of the duplicate, something I've done a few times (I voted to close a duplicate, not realising that the other was already closed)

> I have seen many useful information in "duplicate" posts. [hayalci](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/feature-request-inverse-duplicate-listing/1351#1351)

Currently, if there is useful answers in the duplicate they basically disappear. They are really hard to find, even if you search:

> - I've seen thematically identical questions asked with ZERO words in common. Last time I checked, Lucene wasn't magical faerie dust, unfortunately.. :) [[source]](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/#comment-20685)

With proposed inverse-dupe links, you have a list of other *very* similar questions, which you can check for other useful answers if you're really interested in the question.

Perhaps the inverse-duplicates could be accessed by a link next to the edit/retag/flag/close, just below the tags? Something like..

[image: Inverse duplicate mockup]

Not sure about the wording, it's a bit long, but it seems to me a sensible place to put it..

Another two mockups, based on Shog9 and Ólafur's comments,

*Image Dead - Duplicated by sidebar modification*

Or, a slight variant on the current "Related questions" side bar, which lists (and highlights) exact duplicates:

*Image dead: Related Questions sidebar with dupes highlighted*

I quite like the last one - it's not as big of a change, doesn't much extra clutter (no new tabs/links under question), and is a sensible place - duplicates are "related questions" after all.

Comment: UI seems a bit subtle... how about a sidebar box in the fashion of "Related"?

Comment: How about a Tab like mechanism (similar to the ones for oldest / newest / votes. But for one that says "Duplicate questions" or "Similar questions" where you could browse those linked to this one.

Answer (score 2):

see

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the issue you raise is important. I have seen many useful information in "duplicate" posts.

But maybe merging would be a better idea for these cases.

Comment: With merging you have to be very careful. Since many questions are voted duplicate but aren't 100% duplicates and aren't asked in the same way. So you could have answers that seem very out of place. Unless you program in some mechanism to switch between merged items.