# Two Questions in One

Tags: feature-request, questions

Many times I've written a question, which are answered very well.  But the direction that I'm taking is now pointing me to more questions.  So while I can just go ahead and post a new question, I still need to explain.  For example:

> Talking about [Should there be a way to link questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/should-there-be-a-way-to-link-questions), Why the need for blah blah blah...

Whenever a question is answered it just opens the door to more concepts and ideas.  Therefore I propose that the Question Asker be able open a new question under his original with follow-up questions.  Instead of the current system of linking one question to another, I'd like to be able to ask a question that spawns from another question *inside the same page*.

Obviously there are some spam concerns, but this is just an idea.  Technically this could be a lot of effort for no reason, but then again maybe it could work.

Answer (score 7):

I would rather have questions asked in multiple questions than someone trying to lump them all into one post. I think it leads far too often to some people concentrating on some points, some people concentrating on others, and a lot of people ignoring the rest.

Sure someone could then come in and compile the best answers and try to answer all of them, but I think it is more convenient for everyone (including future users) if the questions stay separated (and if necessary, provide links to other relevant questions).

Comment: that was my concern. That it will be all jumbled up and you wont know left from right. This comes back to linking.. Could we have a section above Related Questions name User Related Question that will be only editable by the Question Asker?.. Lol this just spawned a new Question

Comment: Then you should post it as a another question/suggestion/feature request. I don't personally like the idea (just seems like even more stuff jammed on the sidebar to me) but you may get a different response from the rest of the community.

Comment: It shouldn't be in the sidebar...perhaps below the question, much like the "possible duplicates" go on the top, anyone (the original author or another user) should be able to make a new question and make the two questions linked to each other automatically.

Comment: I like that idea a bit better. I just want to keep from having too much "stuff" everywhere.

Comment: +1 - Future users searching the site are my main concern with run-on questions.  Better to separate them out so people can find specific issues more easily.

Comment: But thats why we say put the User Related Question

Comment: @Shahmir, The OP could simply edit the question and add something like this: "Update: I posted a separate question about X here: [link]". I don't think new functionality is needed for this.

Comment: @Jonik Its what i was talking about. It could be done but i was only suggesting it would be nice to have question links or a pannel that says User related Question

Answer (score 4):

**Make your questions stand alone.** Link to other questions if they might help me understand where you're coming from, but don't *require* me to read or understand a different question before reading your new one.

Just because they're related in your mind, or through some project you're working on, doesn't mean they'll be related for the next 800 people who come looking for an answer to one or the other. Make them stand alone, and then the answers can stand alone too. And those 800 people asking the same questions for different reasons can still benefit from the answers already written.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there should be a way to link questions, perhaps similar to what happens when a question is closed for being an exact duplicate. Instead, however, a user who reads a question and answer can spawn a new question and then the two questions become linked. The only difference would be "spawned" questions would be linked to following the body of the question and duplicates are at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather see separate questions.

Each question has a title, and the title should be meaningful.  It should describe the question so that a reader is likely to know whether the question is interesting or not.
If there's two questions in one, what do we put in the title?  If it's not excessively long, it's likely to be confusing or uninformative about at least one of the questions.