# Consider adding relations between questions

Tags: feature-request, related-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should there be a way to link questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/should-there-be-a-way-to-link-questions)

On stackoverflow.com a lot of questions are related e.g. people keep mentioning "this issue was discussed before here".

Would it be nice to have a "Related questions" section where users can add/vote questions?

How about a "Merged view" where all the answers of related questions are combined in a single list (might be useful for research), sortable by votes/date/activity as is now

The "relationship" relation should be [reflexive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation) - but I am not sure about being [transitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) !

EDITED: In the meantime I found out there is a **related** question!
[Should there be a way to link questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/should-there-be-a-way-to-link-questions)

Answer (score 2):

We customarily just link between two related questions, as you've done here.

Comment: I know but when you are researching a topic it is difficult to find all linked questions and answers; the keywords driven section "Related" helps, the search feature helps as well. But it is about it. I think something like Wikipedia's "See also" section can be helpful http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Guide_to_layout