# Enable comment-style voting on links in related questions section [UP - "related" / FLAG - "not even close"]

Tags: feature-request, voting, related-questions

The related question section that is generated for each question is quite good. I often find where questions that do relate to the original one. Human feedback can make it even better.

#### Stage 1. Just show the votes

#### Stage 2. Feed voting data to spam filters:

- to improve suggestions while asking questions
- to increase connectivity on the site (add top N related questions in the question body, accent on avoiding false positive - do not add unrelated questions)
- to drop unrelated questions from "Related Questions" section (accent on avoiding false negative - do not drop related questions)

#### Related

- [Consider adding relations between questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30434/consider-adding-relations-between-questions-closed)
- [Should there be a way to link questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/should-there-be-a-way-to-link-questions) - *if my suggestion is implemented the links are added by Community user automatically*.

Answer (score 2):

Largely in favor of this kind of thing, but I have several questions/concerns:

- Just what does "Related" mean. I think that his is even less clear than "duplicate", and we'd want some verbiage as a guide. Something like *"People who are interested in this question might also be interested in these others."*?
- Rep limit for voting? I assume so, and would put it at an intermediate level: either 100 (like editting CW posts) or 500 (like retagging).
- Clutter? The layout is pretty dense already, and this will make it more so.

Comment: 1. "Related" means whatever people want it to be (different people might have different views). The only bias is initial computer-generated pool of links to vote.

Comment: 2. I see no point in rep limit (except to discourage bots)

Comment: 3. Comment-style voting is unobtrusive. All controls may be hidden until on mouse-over.

Comment: 2) I suggest a rep limit because we want this filtering done by people who have some level of dedication to the site (even voting requires 15/100 rep). Further, this is not a core function of the site, so excluding low rep users doesn't prevent them from benefiting.  3) Comment style voting *is* unobtrusive (admirably so), but it does take up some room (always horizontal, and often vertical as well).

Comment: @dmckee: On p.3: I can't see any reason why the voting *must* take any space at all when the controls are not active. It is a deficiency of current implementation.