# What are the hidden features of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, hidden-features

What features of Stack Exchange sites do you consider "hidden"?

Comment: See also [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: @Arjan I like how you had to link to that page so that it wouldn't be an unlinked page...

Comment: This​ question.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Attached Firefox/Internet Explorer search plugin.  In Firefox, when you are on Stack Overflow, just click on the search dropdown (to the left of the search text field) and hit **Add "Stack Overflow"**.

EDIT: SO-family sites now also support OpenSearch, as described in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55646/how-does-chrome-know-how-to-search-meta).

Comment: Does this only work on Windows?  It doesn't work on the ancient version of Firefox on my CentOS box.

Comment: It has to support the "manage search plugins" option, and have discovery working.  I'm using Firefox 3.0.2 on Fedora 9, so it definitely works under linux.  It may just be that your version of firefox doesn't autodiscover.

Comment: Take a look a the originating post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830/firefox-and-ie7-users-here-is-your-stackoverflow-search-plugin .  You will need to adjust it since that was for beta.stackoverflow.com (if it doesn't still work).  But you can manually add it with that.

Comment: In Opera, you can right click on the SO search box and click "Create Search" to add it to your list of search sites.

Comment: Cool, but nowhere near hidden. Lots of sites have this (more should!). And you can add sites yourself easily by generating the needed XML by searching a site for TEST and entering the resulting URL into http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/searchguide/en-uk/default.mspx

Comment: It get's better if you assign a keyword to StackOveflow as search engine for Firefox (e.g. "so"). You can then type something like "so python+hidden" directly as URL into Firefox.

Comment: Bookmark for quick search in FF/IE (or search engine shorcut in chrome) is, for searching: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s or for taggeg questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%s

Comment: Cool - I just noticed in IE that the little drop down next to teh search box turns slightly orange when you're on this site.  Sweeeet.

Comment: @Chris or on any other search box, for that matter.

Comment: It's also there in the Brave browser. With appropriate settings, I can type `so: whatever-I-want-to-look-for` in my search bar and it shows me StackOverflow posts.

Answer (score 194):

If you need to tell someone to do keyboard commands you can use the `kbd` HTML tag.

**Source**

```
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>
```

**Result**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>

Comment: More here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html

Comment: That's a standard HTML tag, though; it just has a really nice CSS style.

Comment: You've revealed my greatest tool in making my footer reference links look cool.

Comment: It’s actually *abuse* of [standard HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-kbd-element) to use `<kbd>` for a single key.

Comment: @user3840170 No it is not; the WHATWG spec you linked to does not mention any such stipulation.

Answer (score 167):

Clicking on Days Visited or Consecutive Days on your own profile page

[image: clicking on Days Visited]

opens a calendar that shows which days the site was actually visited.

[image: shows a calendar]

Comment: Nice! Never tried that. Good one.

Comment: @Gabriel - também gostei do calendário e valeu um Badge para mim (I also like the calendar and I got a badge for it) :-)  "You've earned the Necromancer badge for Hidden features of Stack Overflow" - this *message* is great too, just right for Halloween!

Comment: Gaaah, just WHY are half of these features so damn hidden? I know why, Jeff likes hide & seek!...

Comment: It already says I visited tomorrow.  Now I am tempted to stay off tomorrow to create a space time paradox.  Either that or the official time zone is different than my local time, but where's the fun in that?

Comment: I was on my 97th consecutive day when I forgot to visit stackoverflow.com ... almost got my fanatic badge...

Comment: Related: *[Implementation date for the consecutive days calendar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/implementation-date-for-the-consecutive-days-calendar)*.

Comment: yeah me too marlon :((

Comment: Okay I actually discovered this by accident when I was trying to find out why my counter was reset...silly me for missing a day

Comment: FYI: Your OpenID is actually still readable in this answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore...

Comment: @user141148 Nevermind, it does work. It seems to only work for your own profile, though.

Comment: @SolomonUcko This feature is definitely gone now.

Comment: [It went out of fashion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive): *"The consecutive visit calendar UI has gone away. ... Dropped the profile views metric entirely ... it’s a potentially toxic metric.... It’s a vanity metric"*

Comment: This feature was removed for a time, but was restored after a while for a user's own profile and when used by moderators. Recently, there was a bug that prevented it from working, but that was fixed not all that long ago. At this point, this feature is working for moderators and when non-moderators view their own profile.

Comment: @Tink yeah, until the next time it will stop working, in 6-8 hours/days/weeks.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Then flag it again and I'll press delete again. And if it starts working after that again, someone can flag it again and I'll undelete it again. Right now it works, so it should be undeleted.

Comment: @Tink huh didn't notice it was deleted. Don't think that when a hidden feature is gone the answer about it should be deleted, if anything it has historical value, so we know what used to be here. A notice can be added on top of such answers instead, I do that sometimes.

Answer (score 144):

[site://reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Displays all the votes (negatives and positives) you have had, and the question where you've got them.

Also display how much reputation was earned from suggested edits.

Source: [Jeff’s answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46673/rep-cap-kicking-in-a-little-too-early/46680#46680)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd used to be correct, but due to changes since his comment was posted, /reputation no longer has any effect on your reputation, it simply displays what you currently have.

Comment: @Richard as far as I know, it's still possible to recalc and it's still making changes in rare cases where it wasn't updated automatically. IMO this answer should stay. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124330/152859) a related post.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I stand corrected, they removed the button. :(

Answer (score 104):

**[URL tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)**

```
**[URL tooltips][1]**

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
        (Check "Advanced Links" paragraph)
```

Inline [URL tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

```
Inline [URL tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help "Check "Advanced Links" paragraph")
```

Comment: talk about hidden, I'm going to use this in every post now just to show it to people who edit them.

Comment: I didn't know how to do that in markdown until now. I always used an html `<a>` element with a `title` attribute.

Comment: How the hell can you just nest double quotes without the world immediately collapsing?

Comment: @dimlostfaithinSE by the power of stack we will prevail!

Answer (score 95):

You can [see the history](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) of what happened to a post (question and answer) by going to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/{post_id}/timeline
```

In the details that [are shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/8211/timeline), a lot can be clicked to expand.

This also works on [Area 51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#area51).

---

2020-01-16 update: [A link to the respective timeline page is now always visible on each post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/168244).

Answer (score 79):

The "Modified" timestamp of a question is a link to the latest activity post:

[image: modified timestamp with red circle]

Comment: This is probably the awesomest of all things I have learned today.

Comment: Wow... you're telling me that I could have been doing **this** instead of doing CTRL-F and typing "ago"? :O

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is this referring to? I can't find this.

Comment: @KerrekSB check at the right sidebar of any question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAsv9.png

Answer (score 65):

You can see [recently completed features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed%2bfeature-request?sort=newest) on Meta Stack Exchange.  There is also a [formally-maintained list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: if only we could hide everything that's not a feature, like retags.

Comment: Good point. Updated the link so it only shows questions tagged status-completed *and* feature-request.

Comment: And when noticing changes: consider adding them to the community maintained [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 58):

The nofollow attribute on your profile website link is removed at a rep of 2000.

[Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55842/no-follow-attribute-set-in-user-profile-website-link-why/55843#55843)

Comment: Also mentioned in the podcast, [episode 15](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-15/download) (2011-08-10, 30.1 MB, episode 100 in the old numbering scheme) at 43 min 00 secs.

Answer (score 57):

If you have 1000+ reputation, you can click the score of a question/answer and expand the net value to see the total of upvotes vs total of downvotes

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747)

Comment: Good addition.  I wonder how casual users will discover this feature.

Comment: Well, how will the 1k rep users who don't visit meta discover the feature?

Comment: I think the low publicity is intended, Jeff was against this

Comment: By misclicking (with the intention to vote). I just discovered it half an hour ago on SO... and wondered why it wasn't working on my meta account, until I found this.

Comment: @Justin Nelson, it's listed on the `sitename.com/faq` page.  Granted, explicit instructions aren't provided, but a simple mouseover does the trick.

Comment: @popular kind of wondering but what's the reason for needing 1k rep to use this feature?

Comment: @Victor, you'd have to ask a developer for an official answer, but I think they once said it was to prevent too many database accesses.

Comment: @Victor Popular Demand is right, see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/152859) by Jeff.

Answer (score 55):

### [Wildcards in tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32919/ignore-tags-using-wild-card)

Adding `*C#*` to your ignored tags will ignore any tag that contains the letters C#, including `C#-4.0` and `visual-C#-express-2010`. Likewise for favorite tags.

This is useful because there are often questions tagged `C#-3.0` but not `C#`, so just ignoring C# wouldn't catch this. Its a really nice solution to ignoring all questions on a given topic.

You can even use it to ignore all questions not in your favorite tags by just ignoring `*` :D

Comment: Single most useful feature I've seen yet. I don't know why I didn't think to try that!

Comment: Note that wildcarding returns a maximum of 20 tags, so if you set a really generic term as a filter with wildcards you may still get tags appearing that you don't want to see.

Answer (score 49):

I [recently learned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56326/autoindent-of-source-code) that the Your Question/Your Answer editor has an auto-indent feature (in source code blocks): Try Shift+Enter.

Comment: Actually Shift+Enter is a continue formatting command: I.e. it doesn't continue extra indenting within code, but it does add the first 4 needed spaces if you're already in code. It also adds the next numeric value for a numbered list, a copy of the first mark for an unnumbered list, and for both of the latter it "fixes" the other numbers/marks to be sequential/the same. It also continues > blockquotes.

Comment: @Mark Hurd: Great comment! You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 48):

You can search for multiple tags by typing them in the URL separated by `%20`.  This does an **AND** search, i.e. only questions with *all* the tags you specified will be shown.

For example:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows%20com

searches for both the 'windows' and the 'com' tags

Alternatively you can type the following in the search box in the top right for the same results:

> [windows] [com]

Comment: It'd be nice if they enabled the word 'AND' but i'm happy to learn about this, thanks.

Comment: You can also do "tag1 or tag2" in the URL.

Comment: In fact, I think the "not" keyword works as well.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30371/when-a-tag-page-is-viewed-populate-the-search-box-with-that-tag

Comment: `[or]` is now a tag so you can do `[foo][or][bar]` in the search box.

Comment: [or] is no longer a tag; I imagine that's because it wasn't intended as a search operator, it was intended to act like the rest of the [tag:tags]. ;)

Answer (score 47):

Typing `---` in chat forces a new section. Usually, consecutive chat messages from the same user are kept in the same box.

[image]

It is hidden in the transcript, but the separation between sections is still visible:

[image]

Answer (score 47):

Start a blockquote with `>!` for:

> spoilers!

Comment: This is literally a hidden feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature causes accessibility issues: [Spoilers are inaccessible to keyboard-only users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301971/340816).

Answer (score 45):

**Tag links**:

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Syntax: `[tag:tag-name]`

**Meta tags:**

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) (red because it's moderator only tag)

Syntax: `[meta-tag:tag-name]`

Comment: There's also the `[meta-tag:tag-name]` syntax, and it might be nice to link to the MSO post in question here

Comment: More ways to link: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 45):

Comment timestamp is a permalink to that comment: (need to right click it --> copy link address)

> [image]

In the above example clicking that timestamp leads [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow#comment118288_31491).

Comment: Adding comment so I can see this feature.

Comment: @KevinPanko You failed to seize the opportunity to do a [self-referential comment link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange#comment761308_172459), there

Comment: @sehe now real magic is [doing it without editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/761316)!

Comment: ‮: yrt em tel, tub gnitaehc

Comment: @ShadowWizard ^ does that count?

Comment: @sehe nope, not relevant. The trick was predicting the ID that was about to be given to the new comment.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know :) I like my try better o.O

Comment: @sehe how did you get everything typed backwards?

Comment: @ahorn http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229336/152859

Answer (score 43):

[#stackoverflow](http://webchat.freenode.net?channels=stackoverflow) IRC channel on freenode, and the SObot that will post new questions in the channel as they're posted.

Comment: never knew the IRC channel existed! great find!

Comment: @George: It's not a support channel! It's a mostly off-topic channel for socialising. (I speak as one of the very first people to come to that channel, back when it started in August 2008. It was founded by non-SO-staff, and even now, SO staff coverage is very thin; Geoff Dalgas comes in occasionally, but nobody else.)

Comment: Also, sobot is now in its own channel, #sobot. (zigdon is the owner of sobot, so, if he had an account on meta, I'm sure he'd update the post to say so.)

Comment: Fortunately there is no such bot, or the channel would be unusable.

Comment: Back in '09 there was, it was great. Not shocked it no longer runs though.

Answer (score 40):

It's possible to view the markup used to create any question or answer. (This may be useful if you wish to combine answers or quote part of the question with formatting.)

If the question or answer has been edited so that it has an **edited X timeunits ago** link, you can use that to view the revision history, then use the **view source** link.

If it hasn't been edited then you can still view the revision history, but you'll have to manually enter the url in your browser's address bar. For questions, take the number in the middle of the page's url; for answers use the *link* link for the answer to get it's unique number in the anchor of the url (after the # character) and then go to:

http://stackoverflow.com/posts/***number***/revisions

Comment: A feature like this should not be hidden.

Comment: I usually just click "edit". Now that even low reputation users can click edit, this is not very hard to find.

Comment: Although it's still useful, since low-rep users can't edit on meta sites.

Answer (score 36):

I just noticed today that ***asker*** comments are shaded just like the background for the user box:

[image]

This applies in comments to everything for that particular question too. It can be handy for context on larger pages.

Comment: this feature doesn't seem too _hidden_

Answer (score 33):

Sending a chat message consisting solely of `this is fine` now oneboxes to this comic:

[image: this is fine]

If you want to test this for yourself, please use the [Sandbox room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) to avoid bothering others.

Comment: How... how did you find?! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hat hunting for Winterbash :)

Answer (score 30):

When you [search for a popular keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hibernate) the search gets auto-converted to a tag search.

[hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) - results: 6,560 questions **tagged** [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate)

You can ***override that*** by prefixing a plus sign.

[`+hibernate`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bhibernate) - results: 4,807 search results for posts **containing** [`+hibernate`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bhibernate) 
<sup>(some of which are not *tagged* [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate))</sup>

Comment: _The top (n) tags in the tag list are automatically turned into tags when they appear in searches_ ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47829/209901))

Answer (score 28):

**Modify tags in question (hidden area at right of tag list):**

[image]

**Note:** This is only available with 10k rep or more.

Comment: What's the difference between that and [retag question](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) that requires only 500 rep?

Comment: @HuBeZa It's the same function with another user interface.

Comment: @HuBeZa also the retag link is removed after hitting 2K.

Comment: The “retag question” function / privilege seems to have gone away⁠ altogether.

Answer (score 27):

Well, not only related to Stack Overflow but also AWESOME: [ODATA for all Stack Exchange sites](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

There's even some saved queries to know. For example, how much is still missing for me to get the X badge.

This is awesome!

Comment: It is great, yes. Hopefully Area51 will soon be added.

Comment: OData is unfortunately disabled now on SEDE it won't comeback.

Answer (score 26):

You can write small text using `<sub><sup>` trick. For example wrapped with "single" `<sub><sup>`:

<sub><sup>hello world</sup></sub>

With two:

<sub><sup><sub><sup>hello world</sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: Don't do that. It's an abuse of the markup, which is supposed to be for superscripts and subscripts. And it'll look horrible if you have multiple lines of text.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I just shared something I've seen lots of times here, not my idea. But personally I think that since we don't have any `<small>` tag it can be useful to show small sized text.

Comment: Works as a charm for `<sup>[Image source](url)</sup>` links under images.

Answer (score 26):

Every site on Stack Exchange network has a "network login help" page, which run a few tests to check for the availability of certain necessary features in the user's browser.

To reach the page just append `/network-login-help` to the URL of any site, e.g. for the main site: https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help

Comment: Does this feature still exist? The help page certainly does, but I don't think I've ever seen the behavior described in the blog!

Answer (score 26):

When you upload an image, you can append these characters to its name to get:

- *s* -> small square fixed at 90×90
- *b* -> big square fixed at 160×160
- *t* -> small thumb, 160×160
- *m* -> medium thumb (max 320?)
- *l* -> large thumb (max 640?)
- *h* -> huge thumb (max 1024?)
- add ?s=X for a custom size (X=16,32,64,128,256 or 512 ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296138/209901)))

Original:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD5G.png
```

[image: Original]

Small square:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD5Gs.png
                               ^
```

[image: small square]

Big square:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD5Gb.png
                               ^
```

[image: big square]

Small thumbnail:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD5Gt.png
                               ^
```

[image: Thumbnail]

Medium thumbnail:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD5Gm.png
                               ^
```

[image: Medium]

Large thumbnail:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD5Gl.png
                               ^
```

[image: Large]

Huge thumbnail:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD5Gh.png
                               ^
```

[image: Medium]

Custom size: e.g. 16x16

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD5G.png?s=16
                                   ^^^^^
```

[image: Custom]

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a feature of imgur.com and not of [SE]. This is documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74312/195817) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/195817).

Answer (score 24):

View other users' privileges page by visiting `/help/privileges/user/<id>` URL. This page is accessible without any restrictions which seems to be [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188183/166025).

<sup>Came to know about this feature from a post made by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson).</sup>

Answer (score 24):

To find the age of specific site, you can view the profile of the site's Community account, then the "member for" is the site age since this is the very first account ever created on each site.

For example on [puzzling site](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community): (URL template is `//[site].com/users/-1/community`)

> [image]

Easier than going to the [full sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and  looking for the site you want. :)

Answer (score 22):

Quick access to see user's review stats: daily, weekly, monthly and total, plus last time he/she reviewed.

URL format is: `https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/[review queue ID]/[user ID]`

Review queue ID list:

1. Suggested Edits
2. Close Votes
3. Low Quality Posts
4. First Posts
5. Late Answers
6. Reopen Votes
7. ? (future use, or maybe available on specific non SO sites only)
8. Broken Links
9. ? (future use, or maybe available on specific non SO sites only)
10. Triage
11. Help & Improvement

Some examples, using Geoff as model (and rene for the latest queues):

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/1/2
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/2/2
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/3/2
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/10/578411 (triage)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/11/578411 (Help & Improvement)

**This is just raw data, unformatted and of course can be changed or taken down at any point**.

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi stop making useless edits please. They do **NOT** tidy up anything, and in this case made the post worse. For example, "user's" is the correct English word. If you don't know, **do not edit**. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really see how Mehdi's edit made the post worse. It was minor, but I think most of it was an improvement. The only part I'm not sure about preserving the original intent is the "maybe" -> "may be". I think "users'" can make sense (as in "review stats of users").

Comment: @starball nope. You can't see multiple users reviews in one place, you see single user reviews each time, so "user's" is the only correct word. "maybe" to "may be" is just, well, silly, and the only fair change was "he/she" to "them" but I was so annoyed it didn't matter.

Answer (score 20):

All the editing keyboard shortcuts act as toggles, including add hyperlink.

Comment: I didn't even know there *were* keyboard shortcuts!

Comment: what are the shortcuts? where can I find them?

Comment: @Gabriel: Hover over the buttons above the textarea and a tooltip will tell you what it does and what the keyboard shortcut for it is.

Comment: Thanks @Sam never noticed that.

Answer (score 19):

It's not a very hidden feature that, on Stack Overflow, the HTML `<title>` of each question page will have the most popular tag prepended.

What **is** hidden is that if the person names the question with the tag anywhere in the title:

> [Java] How do I do this thing

or

> How do I do this thing in Java

It will *not* also prepend `java -` at the beginning of the HTML title!

Answer (score 17):

If you hover over a username in the comments section of a question you get to see their reputation.

Comment: this appears for all comment's usernames (questions and answers on all sites), good find!.  slight niggle is i often only on the second or third time. the username link's title attribute contains the rep, and it's a slow fetch, and then is forgotten after some seconds.

Comment: Confirmed. It still works (2020-10-28). And also in posts (questions and answers), hovering over a user's reputation display. Yes, it is not much, but it shows the ***exact*** score, [e.g. *1,217,083* instead of the immediate display *"1217k"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479).

Answer (score 17):

Comment short links are now available: `http://[site]/posts/comments/[id]`

To obtain comment id you can extract it from the full comment link or use dev tools to inspect the HTML.

For example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/14689

Comment: @ocæon no such button for comments. If you have a share button for comments, it's result of some userscript you installed.

Comment: This shorter URL avoids some possible problems with the links obtained from the timestamps - such as changing the title or multiple pages of answers: [Comment link becomes invalid if question title changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242560) and [Links to comments when the title has been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358749).

Comment: @Martin yeah, good point.

Answer (score 15):

I can't believe no one has mentioned descriptions of Stack Exchange functions and data hidden mostly in tooltips. This came up most recently in [this question about privilege percentages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73184/privilege-percentages-are-confusing). @Arjan commented  **"As always on these sites: when in doubt, hover your mouse over the text for more detail."**

Comment: I think the example you give has been replaced, by a single "next privilege" progress bar on the right, i.e. instead of % progress next to each privilege?

Answer (score 15):

On the personal profile page there is a **Tags** list  just before **Badges**. There, some numbers are written before and after the tag, like

**`162`** [php](/questions/tagged/php) × 302

When you **hover** on that tag you can see the total statistics of

- How many questions you have asked within that tag
- How many questions you have answered in that tag and
- How many upvotes you have received in that tag

**For example**, if I hover on the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag, I see these on the tooltip:

> Asked 71 non-wiki questions with a total score of 56. Answered 230 non-wiki questions with a total score of 162.

**302** is the sum of total questions and answers in the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag
**162** is the sum of votes for answers in the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag

### UPDATE

Recently I found one more hidden feature.

In the comment box, you can not notify more than one user, that is, you can not use `@` more than once (until it is inside tilde). Doing so, you will get the warning below.

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified

Comment: sorry can't see the point of making it bold.

Comment: okay.np. you are right

Answer (score 15):

You can get raw view of post comments (either question or answer) by typing such URL:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/[post id]/comments
```

For example comments on this very question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/8211/comments

Working on all sites of course.

Answer (score 14):

While I answered this question in Stack Overflow:   [How does the Stack Overflow Search Input work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11133206/601179)

I found this hidden feature: If you type your search expression than clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will open a new tab or window with the results for your search expression.

For some  browsers you will need to allow popups in the site to make it work.

---

For the sake of completeness The keydown (`javascript` - jQuery)code looks like this:

```
function(c) {
    if (13 == c.which && c.ctrlKey && d.val()) 
        return window.open("/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(d.val()), "_newtab"), !1
}​
```

Comment: Ummmm that is no hidden feature of stack overflow. That is just a feature of browsers in general....

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA. ummmm. Nope. try it at google. You can see they wrote code to make it work.

Comment: @Norm I have rolled back your edit because this got nothing to do with Stack Exchange, it's a built-in behavior of Chrome: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/d2jrjkng900 (one might start "hidden features of Chrome", but it will be off topic in MSE)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hm, I did try it with Google search for comparison and it didn't open a new page there...

Comment: @Norm I suspect it's due to client side scripting being used by Google, overriding the browser default behavior. SE's search box is plain `<input type="text" />` without a submit button, no auto complete or anything like that.

Comment: 'ctrl+enter for open in tab' is a trend supported by many sites _and_ many browsers, with varying dependancies and degrees of success. this is still of note if stackexchange currently _adds_ support for it.

Answer (score 14):

View all linked questions of any post using the format:  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/<post_id>`

These could be further sorted as:

1. Hot
2. Newest
3. Votes
4. Active
5. Unanswered

For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/3102819 shows a page having all questions linked to/from "[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102819/447356)" post.

Comment: That's not hidden when it is needed. At the bottom of the __Linked__ column on the RHS of the Q&As there's a link "see more linked questions…", such as for the question you've used as an example. This feature _is_ hidden, i.e. still available but unlinked, for Q&As with only a few linked questions that all fit on the RHS.

Comment: @Mark it's still useful as a standalone way to view linked questions, many of the "hidden features" here are available somehow otherwise people won't have much chance of finding them. :)

Answer (score 12):

Putting a parameter `?lastactivity` at the end of the question's URL will redirect you to the last activated (modified) post.

E.g. [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/?lastactivity`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/?lastactivity)

Comment: Nice, did you find it yourself or after reading [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146960/152859)? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nope. Actually today my internet connection is slow. And clicking on *modified 1 min ago* in the http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active page redirected me to `questionsURL/?lastactivity` which I was able to see that in browser's URL bar.

Answer (score 11):

**[Stack Overflow Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)**

[image]

Comment: ...how is this hidden?

Answer (score 10):

You can determine the total number of active users by looking at how many people have the "Teacher" badge (posted at least one upvoted answer):

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1/teacher

Comment: Is that right? I interpret the badge description as just users who posted at least one answer *that was voted up*, which should be number less or equal to the total number of users that posted at least one answer. Right?

Comment: While the "Teacher" badge isn't exactly a perfect measure of user activity, the fact that we can do measurements of how many people have which badges is valuable. For any predetermined badge criteria, see how many people meet it. Poor man's marketing statistics really.

Answer (score 10):

Associating your Stack Overflow login with another Stack Exchange site gives you +100 free reputation on that site, which adds to your combined total. Most people on Meta probably know about this already, but there's nothing I can find about it in the FAQ.

Comment: It is mentioned in [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) and on the blog, [Cross-Site Account Associations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/). And [the keyword is bonus](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bonus).

Comment: @Arjan: Huh, cool links. I'd still call it hidden, though; I didn't even know those pages existed until just now. :)

Comment: +1 because so many people have no idea about this bonus :)

Comment: Only if you have 200 rep on the other site.

Answer (score 9):

If you click on a question that was migrated, it takes you to the question on the site of migration. If you then click on the "Migrated" (with capital M) link, it will then take you back to the revision history on the first site. [Note: it used to take you to the old question stub which was cooler]

Comment: And at the original one can also see the edit history prior to the migration (by, as usual, clicking the time next to "edited", if applicable).

Comment: this answer may need updating. behaviour may be incosistant or may have changed, for example, this page it'self was originally posted on stackoverflow, and clicking the 'migrated from' link goes directly to the old revision history, _not_ the stub. is this simply because the stub no longer exists?

Answer (score 9):

When providing links, people have always been writing

```
[Link text][1]

  [1]: http://example.com/
```

That doesn't look very great if there's a bunch of them

```
[Lorem ipsum dolor][1] sit amet, [consectetur adipisicing][2] elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
[incididunt ut labore][3] et dolore [magna aliqua][4]. Ut enim ad [minim veniam][5], quis
[nostrud exercitation][6] ullamco [laboris][7] nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
[Duis aute irure][8] dolor in [reprehenderit][9] in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. [Excepteur sint occaecat][10] cupidatat non [proident][11], sunt in
[culpa qui officia][12] deserunt [mollit][13] anim [id est laborum][14].

  [1]: http://example.com/1
  ...
  [14]: http://example.com/14
```

However, you can make your post look better (don't let links interrupt you) by omitting the number (or custom texts) and simply use link texts. This will also make your link section look better:

```
[Lorem ipsum dolor] sit amet, [consectetur adipisicing] elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
[incididunt ut labore] et dolore [magna aliqua]. Ut enim ad [minim veniam], quis
[nostrud exercitation] ullamco [laboris] nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
[Duis aute irure] dolor in [reprehenderit] in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. [Excepteur sint occaecat] cupidatat non [proident], sunt in
[culpa qui officia] deserunt [mollit] anim [id est laborum].

  [Lorem ipsum dolor]: http://example.com/1
  ...
  [id est laborum]: http://example.com/14
```

In fact, this has surely messed up some FAQs in Markdown source. Editing those FAQs is somehow a suffering if you want to add/modify links.

Comment: but editing text used in links means having to edit it twice...nice alt anyhow

Comment: Wait, what? A non-CW answer here??

Answer (score 7):

The Review icon appears when you reach a Reputation of 500, enough to perform review actions. It then appears in the top bar between the recent achievements icon and the help icon.

Until then you can still use this link to show history of edits suggested to you!
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history

Comment: Not hidden anymore..

Answer (score 7):

**Shortcut to the Advanced Search Options**

Just search for an empty (or 1 character length) query and you will see the page.

**Note:** it is not recommended to link to this URL, use it for personal use only as this method of accessing might disappear in the future leaving a bunch of broken links.

Answer (score 7):

You can run queries against the database for any Stack Exchange site with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

I did not know about this feature, or see it linked, until I read a Meta Stack Overflow post which used this example.

[Query for Most Common Comments on Stack Overflow.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/106491/most-common-comments)

*Although now I know it exists. I've found the link in the footer.

Comment: So its not really hidden then :P

Comment: It's hiding behind a curtain but it's feet are still showing.

Answer (score 7):

There are `dev` subdomains.

- For stackoverflow.com, it is [dev.stackoverflow.com](//dev.stackoverflow.com)
- For meta.stackexchange.com, it is `meta.dev.stackexchange.com` (cannot be linked from here directly because the renderer rewrites it to the nonexistent URL `dev.meta.stackexchange.com`)
- For area51.stackexchange.com, it is [dev.area51.stackexchange.com](//dev.area51.stackexchange.com)
- For stackexchange.com, it is [dev.stackexchange.com](https://dev.stackexchange.com)
- (I don't know what the domains are for other network sites. I tried probing for them and failed. They might not exist.)

If you go to the homepage of one as a non-staff user, you'll see:

> Warning: this site is for Stack Exchange developers and staff - it is used for development and testing.
>
> To log in, you must have received an invitation email. Click the invitation link in the email to log in!

I'm guessing that means that the data there is writable and periodically refreshes to match the production ("real") data, and that modifications to that data are separate from modifications to the production data.

However, you don't need to be logged in to fetch many page resources, like the CSS and JS, which exist there in non-[minified](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Minification) form, which can be useful if you want to do some digging into the front end source code.

I learned about this from [@double-beep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/435726).

Comment: https://dev.superuser.com/ also appears to exist, which I only discovered because it's listed on the [Dev Stack Exchange Digests page](https://dev.stackexchange.com/digests). Server Fault and WebApps are both listed as well, but neither of those seemingly work.

Answer (score 6):

#### Shortening questions and answers [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)

Given the following URL to an answer on Stack Overflow:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988444/why-is-the-llvm-execution-engine-faster-than-compiled-code/7250716#7250716
```

We can delete the middle text part, change the question to 'q' and leave only the answer number and still have a working URL : :)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/q/7250716
```

[Try it!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7250716)

While this way is not recommended, it is supported and works - according to what [@genesis wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104552/shortening-urls-of-stackoverflow-q-and-a/104557#104557).

---

For further shorthand (especially when writing comments where every character counts), you can drop the protocol from the link:

```
//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211
```

[Try it!](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211)

---

If you're linking to a post on the same site, you don't even need to specify the site's domain name - just the path, eg:

```
/q/8211
```

[Try it!](/q/8211)

Comment: Hidden feature? You can click on the `link` button under any question to get this link...

Comment: That's not really "hidden" - try the "link" link below the question! (This gives you an additional `/168089` in the end, which can be safely removed - this number is you user number, it indicates that it was you who posted that link.)

Comment: @Kobi: Almost `:-)`

Comment: @Kobi you mean "share". ;)

Comment: you can also use just /a/ instead of /q/ for answers

Answer (score 5):

You can browse directly to answers you have downvoted using a hidden feature of the [stackoverflow.com/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page if you have the answer's unique ID (available on the [Reputation Calculator](http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation) page).

(NOTE: Why you would do this anymore given that the answers are now hyperlinked directly from the Reputation tab is questionable, but it still works anyway.)

1. Browse to the [Reputation Calculator](http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation) and locate a line representing an answer vote.

   They look like:

   `3    XXXXXX (-1)`

   where `XXXXXX` is the answer's unique identifier.
2. Browse to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/XXXXXX where `XXXXXX` is that answer identifier.
3. You will be redirected to another URL in the format
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/YYYYYY/name-of-the-question-here/XXXXXX#XXXXXX

   ...which is a link to the answer that you downvoted on the question `YYYYYY`. That URL you've been directed to is also the one you'll see if you hover over the "link" hyperlink on the answer that you downvoted.

(This actually works for any answer as long as you know the id `XXXXXX`, not just ones that you've downvoted.)

Comment: Nice! You can just search the reputation calculation page for instances of "(-1)" to find all the downvotes you ever cast. :)

Comment: @danny It would be more appropriate to post your alternative method as a separate answer rather than making such a radical edit to mine. I've rolled your edit back.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Of course, that will show you only down votes on answers.

Comment: @Scott I think back then downvotes on questions also cost 1 rep.

Answer (score 5):

**You can reply to yourself in chat.**

1. Go the the perma-link of the message you want to reply to, and get the message number.
2. Type this number preceded by a colon `:message id`
3. Type your message and send!

Comment: _"Now you can send yourself a WhatsApp, email and not just a text, uh oh oh oooh, uh oh oh oooh"_ (and now a SO chat too!) (Song: ID Cover of Gelt, Lipah Shmeltzer)

Comment: You can also use this to reply to messages which are in the future (by editing your message, or predicting the message ID), or even to write a message which replies to itself!

Comment: @pxeger it's very hard to reply to future messages when chat is active (i.e. there are messages in several chat rooms), as the message you reply to must be on same chat room.

Answer (score 5):

https://www.isstackoverflowdownforeveryoneorjustme.com/ redirects to the Stack Status page, https://www.stackstatus.net/.

Answer (score 5):

#### Hidden answer sorting options

In addition to the 3 default sorting options:

- Highest score (default): `scoredesc`
- Date modified (newest first): `modifieddesc`
- Date created (oldest first): `createdasc`

There are also the opposite of them:

- Lowest score: `scoreasc`
- Date modified (oldest first): `modifiedasc`
- Date created (newest first): `createddesc`

These values were added on [Revisiting changes to answer sorting menu: better use of space, moving menu into a dropdown, ascending/descending sort options, clearer descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376062/241919). However, while the options have been removed from the dropdown visually, the values are still accepted by the system. Note that this has to be manually entered on the URL, so the easiest way is to select a different sorting option from the dropdown to display the full URL with the sorting parameter `answertab`, then change the value, and execute it.

Note that by using a hidden answer sorting option, the dropdown will show "Highest score (default)" since it cannot find the corresponding option and is the fallback option. However, the hidden sorting will still be in effect.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to post a request asking for questions determined to be duplicates to be listed on the original question, but I found that there was [already a feature request for it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/please-inverse-the-community-users-duplicate-listing) and that it was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because [you can find questions that are duplicates of this one by looking at the "Linked" sidebar](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/). Cool!

(Note: also appearing there, are questions, comments, etc. that link to this question.)

Comment: As an aside: the "linked" section does not only show things linking *to* a question, but also links from posts and comments of the question itself.

Answer (score 4):

In the timeline of a post (e.g. [this timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/8211/timeline)) the timestamp is a permalink to the timeline event, e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/8211/timeline#history_4cd84f95-602a-41d9-8aeb-3f3f6925e4ec). This will show the timeline, with the specific event highlighted.

Answer (score 4):

### The rickroll link on the [declined flags help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/declined-flags) is an actual rickroll

[image]

Comment: how is it a rickroll if it's clearly and non-deceptively labelled?

Answer (score 4):

You can determine if a question that you have a link to is spam/rude deleted or regular deleted without needing 10K tools by viewing the 404 page. If you see no similar questions list then the question was spam/rude deleted:
[image: Spam]

Otherwise the question was deleted by some other means:
[image: Not Spam]

Answer (score 3):

You can view the error page of any given site (presumably without actually causing a server error) by going to the `/error` subdirectory of the site. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/error

Any other random word afterwords seems to just go to the 404 page meaning that the `/error` page is special.

Some of them have rather unique images in their error page.

Comment: Nice!  I liked this one: https://english.stackexchange.com/error

Comment: @JosephStyons I liked this one: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/error too

Answer (score 2):

You can force-sync your per-site Meta reputation with the main site reputation by going to the per-site Meta and clicking the <kbd>Ask Question</kbd> button.

Normally there is a delay between when the reputation a per-site Meta profile becomes synced with the main site profile reputation but I have noticed that trying to ask a question on a per-site Meta will cause them to sync immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no delete link below a post unless post is eligible to be deleted by you, you can view how many delete votes a post has as long as you have the see vote counts privilege, by showing the daily vote summaries in the timeline:

[image: Delete: 1]