# Resizing an image in a post?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, images

Is it possible to resize an image in an answer? For example, *[How important is PhD research topic to getting a job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770841/how-important-is-phd-research-topic-to-getting-a-job)* has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770841/how-important-is-phd-research-topic-to-getting-a-job/770873#770873) that *should* have the image in the answer, but it's too big.

Is there a way to handle resizing?

Comment: Please note that both links are broken. Can you think of another example to replace those links?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens [This is the image](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/resume_comic.png) that was being referred to in those (now deleted) examples.

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Now that all image uploads are stored on Imgur servers, [you can tweak the URL](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/please-try-using-smaller-versions-of-images) to show various sizes [should the original be too large](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-pho/101446#101446).

Where the original might be something as obscenely large as this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBb.jpg
```

Slip an `m` or `s` character at the end of the file name, *just* before the file extension, like so:

#### Medium:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBbm.jpg
```

#### Smaller:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBbs.jpg
```

You can whack in good ol' HTML for that and force client-side resize:

```
<img src="http://example.com/path-to-ghosts.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

But, it's up to you to work out what a good set of resize dimensions will be.

Comment: Note that for some reason this only works on SO if the `src` attribute comes first (before `width` and/or `height`). A while back it really puzzled me that I couldn't get the image working even though the url and everything seemed right...

Comment: The order of `src, width, height` is the convention SOFU sticks to for the wild guns of HTML for images.

Comment: Note: The image `title` goes last. :)

Comment: The image tag does not show when I add `width` or `height`.

Comment: @CiroSantilli You need to put the parameters in order: `src`, `width`, `height`. Ran into the same problem myself and didn't realize the fix until I found this question and followed random's comment.

Comment: @Iszi thanks for the tip, I'll try it out next time I edit an image. Their XSS filter is merciless!

Comment: If you use the `img` tag approach, don't add `px` after the size!

Comment: This breaks the `automatic linking to the image at the same time as displaying it` feature. If you change the url, when you click on it, you will get the same sized picture, not the original one. :(

Comment: This was useful. Thanks! A warning I want to add is that apparently the m/s -modifiers to the imgur file name don't seem to work with animated gifs. At least I only got an appropriately scaled static picture showing the first image of the animated GIF.

Comment: Using only `height` will keep aspect ratio, which is most useful.

Comment: Using just height or width will [scale the image accordingly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/995714)

Comment: **Client-side resize is preferable for Retina displays.** It will display at full native resolution, but still the proper size on the screen (twice the pixel size, but twice the density as well).

Comment: Appending the letter `b` to the end seems to do something as well. For me it was a happy medium between `m` and `s`

Comment: @random, after doing this, the resolution of the image gets spoiled. So, what can be done to tackle this?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw yes `b` means `big`. See the full list of suffixes here [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/995714)

Comment: `m` doesn't seem to work anymore. `s` is tiny. `b` worked okay.

Comment: Actually I take that bag. `b` is cut off...

Comment: It does not work for me

Answer (score 45):

You can also add a query string like `?s=xyz` (with xyz = 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 or 512) after the name of the image to change it from `gSpBi.png` to (eg) `gSpBi.png?s=128`. I.e I just added the query string `?s=128`  right after `.png`. Attention: sometimes part of the top and bottom are not shown (I think it depends a bit on the actual image you're using).

Some examples of using such query string in an image, for xyz = 16, 32, 64, 128:

[image] (`?s=16`)   
[image] (`?s=32`)   
[image] (`?s=64`)   
[image] (`?s=128`)

Btw, the above also shows that you can even insert some text in between 2 images, though such text seems to have these limitations (at least I have no idea yet how to get around those):

- cannot have text that spans more then a single line.
- the vertical alignment of the text is always at the bottom of the image.
- the spacing between the image and text can only be set using `&nbsp;`.

**Note**: The currently accepted answer doesn't mention that you do need to respect [some specific HTML formatting syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/286501), in order to be able to use the `img` HTML tag. E.g. to create these 3 variations (sizes) of an image:

[image: Babou, aka My Patou]
[image: Babou, aka My Patou]
[image: Babou, aka My Patou]

Here is the HTML source that created the previous 3 images:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSpBi.png" width="216" height="180" alt="Babou" title="My Patou">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSpBi.png" width="270" height="225" alt="Babou" title="My Patou">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSpBi.png" width="135" height="113" alt="Babou" title="My Patou">
```

PS: I only learned about these things via browsing of sources, and experimenting, I am not aware of any documentation about this.

Comment: Love it! I needed this for stackoverflow post that my image was way too large in. I had to go with 256, but it works! And, in markdown too:
`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfP0S.png?s=256`

Comment: @NeilGaetanoLindberg merci for the kudos (and upvote). BTW, I saw your edited SO-post in which you added that "?s=256", which indeed does the trick. But just in case you're not aware of it, as a variation you could also have changed that URL to https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfP0S$.png, whereas `$` can have the value `s` (small), `m` (medium) or `l` (large), and in your case 'm' seems to be the best fit.

Answer (score 27):

If it helps anyone else here is one more hack that would make a post readable when referencing large images:

In the description you will have this to reference an image

```
[![My App TouchID authentication][2]][4]
```

At the bottom of the page I have defined 2 images, one was automatically created when I uploaded the image and the second one I created

```
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PieY5m.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PieY5.png
```

Notice the only difference between 2 and 4 is the m. Going back to the markdown for the image

The [2] reference is used inside the image tag uses the medium sized imgur.com image. The [4] next to the image tag references the link that the image would link to, this is the larger image uploaded to imgur. You can replace m.png with s.png as mentioned by random.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 11):

Additionally to previous answers, I've found another mode which is useful where the image is wide. Let's see:

## Using *'t'* (maybe Thumbnail or Tiny) as @dim suggested.

[image: demo]

## Same image in Smaller:

[image: demo]

Comment: You saved my life. I think, however, that "t" could mean "tiny" rather than thumbnail. Because, actually, the "s" mode more resembles a thumbnail than "t", as it is cropped to a square.

Comment: @dim: the [imgur.com documentation](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs) names it *small thumbnail*, and I suspect it was the first resizing option added. I see no evidence anywhere that it was meant to be short for 'tiny'.