# Sort main sites before metas in the mod close dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, moderator-tools

In the migrate-anywhere box, I just almost sent a site to another meta instead of the parent because it was on the top of the list. As we're almost never going to send a question to another site's meta, can we get this list to sort the mains before metas? Metas can either be immediately after their main or after all mains, I'm not really picky about that. But a given site should be before its meta.

[image: metas before mains]

Comment: This has been bothering me too.  Not enough to raise the issue on here, but enough to upvote you.

Comment: They should probably be explicitly hidden unless we type the magic word.

Comment: There've been suggestions to remove meta migration altogether, but I'd say that this order-switchin' would be a much better solution. Though, curiously, in your sample above, Expression Engine Meta is second.

Comment: [I've previously proposed to remove the child metas entirely from that list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174743/improvements-to-the-mod-only-migrate-tool).

Comment: Why is ExpressionEngine an exception?

Comment: @GraceNote I still think entirely removing them from everywhere but MSO would be the better solution, there absolutely no reason to ever migrate to a different site's child meta.

Comment: In a related way, wondering why on earth something like that doesn't exist for closure>off-topic on SO for users. So many questions are off-topic, but we're straight-jacketed in where we can vote to send them.

Comment: @nickhar Most users aren't active on a wide variety of SE sites, so they aren't that familiar with what types of questions are on-topic on other sites. This led to a lot of bad migrations from SO to other sites by well-intentioned users.  The current list of five migration targets are sites where we get it right most of the time.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The crux of bad migrations is no-doubt subject-matter expertise or lack thereof. Its a shame the bar has to be set in this way and because of it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah sure, that absolutely sounds reasonable.  Child metas immediately after their parents will be in the next build for everything but Meta.SO, it will get a merge and a push likely later today.

Comment: Is there a reason why we can't also get MSO either de-listed or listed at the end of any pulldown or just listed below SO?