# Bug when mod migrating - very easy to migrate to a site's Meta instead of main site

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, migration, moderator-tools, per-site-meta

Somewhat related: [Improvements to the mod-only migrate tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174743/improvements-to-the-mod-only-migrate-tool)

Mods have the ability to migrate to any site on the Closing > Off-Topic > Migration page using a text box to select a site. This list contains all sites, including child metas. If you type a site name (like "Programmers" or "Code Review"), you'll end up with two sites (the main and their child meta). For examples, you can see "Programmers" and "Programmers Meta". If you accidentally click "Programmers Meta" and then use your backspace key to remove the word "Meta", then immediately click "Vote to Close", the question will still be migrated to Programmers Meta.

To be explicitly clear: In my specific case, the migration text field said "Code Review" as text. However, because I had previously selected Code Review Meta, that ended up being the target. That is a bug and needs to be resolved.

I know because I just did this, accidentally migrating a question to Code Review Meta instead of Code Review. This is not only not intuitive, but I should be able to type a site name for migration. Otherwise, consider just making this field a combo box instead of an editable combo box, especially if the editing function isn't working right.

Comment: Too funny - [this was broken in 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174753/165931). For a while [it was fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184425/sort-main-sites-before-metas-in-the-mod-close-dialog), but [the bug is back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277124/regression-bug-mso-is-listed-above-so-when-migrating-a-question) Are you asking for a re-sort like I did or some other solution?

Comment: probably related: [What's up with the “Meaning of MIT license”? (5 years old post recently migrated from SO to Programmers meta, then to main)](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6861/31260)

Comment: @bmike The ordering is still correct. The problem is that if you select Meta, but try to migrate to the main by removing the word "Meta" from the box, it will still go to the Meta.

Comment: @ThomasOwens That's devious. Usually - I'm worried that slow javascript or slow network will miss my tap or down arrow to select SO and not MSO which is the usual for me.

Comment: @bmike I think that changing to a standard combo box with all sites preloaded will fox the issue entirely.

Comment: I've now mentioned this in the TL, but I'm afraid that even fixing bugs on features that were previously voted on *and accepted and implemented* is completely outside the realm of what SE is capable of. We'll probably have to wait for at least 100 votes to be completely ignored by SE team.

Answer (score 11):

I cannot think of any meaningful reason why the meta site should even be on a list for migration.

Why not just remove them from the migration target list entirely?

Comment: I agree, but based on the linked question, that has been status-declined. So I'm asking for something that shouldn't be status-declined. This would be preferable, though.

Comment: I would consider listing only sites (as opposed to main-meta pairs) and making meta a separate checkbox (unchecked by default, assuming migration defaults to main site). List would become twice shorter and mod would have to explicitly tick checkbox if they intended to migrate to meta

Comment: +1. For instance, who would migrate from Seasoned Advice.SE to Meta.Arqade.SE or something similar?