# Units in img width/height breaks image

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering, markdown-preview

In both the preview and rendered question, this does not work:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBb.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
```

..as the image doesn't appear (cleaned up by HTML sanitiser presumably):

It should be here →

← (click the edit button to see the source)

However, strangely omitting the `px` unit works:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QBb.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

..for example:

Here →
[image]
←

Comment: (..image was from [this related post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25052/745))

Comment: [According to W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html), height and width are supposed to contain non-negative integers.

Comment: @Antony Ohh, that explains it! For no justifable reason I thought the img width/height would accept things like `50%` and so on - but that would explain it

Comment: The W3C validator also confirms what @Antony says: *Bad value 100px for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead.* Note that it is valid HTML 4, it's just invalid HTML 5.

Comment: @dbr only CSS accepts units, not HTML attributes. :)

Comment: From the linked faq: *width="" (up to 999; **do not include the 'px' extension**)*