# Images should be resized in profile about section

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, images

I have often found that when putting an image into my about section of my profile that a lot of the image is lost due to the fact that it is not resized accordingly with the space provided, nor is there a side scrolling thing available which allows you to view the rest of the image without right-clicking on it and getting the image location and then going to the URL.

For example what I mean is that for instance with this image:

[image]

I loose quite a lot of it when I put it in my about section and there is no easy without actually going to the image's URL to view the rest of it:

[image]

I don't know if this is really a bug, but at least it could be improved upon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing an image in a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes, but in questions and answers it is at least resized not to go off the page, something like this should be applied in the about sections too.

Comment: Did you try the size suggestions in the dupe to see if they also work in your profile? Using the html option will probably be best. You image is too small with`m` and too large with `l` (at least testing on my own profile with your image showed that).

Comment: @DavidPostill The fact that a CSS bug in handling large images can be worked around by not using large images does not mean the report should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it would be nice to prevent images from overflowing the "About me" section in the profile.  A simple solution would be to add the following CSS rule to the SE style sheets:

```css
.user-card .bio img { max-width: 100% }
```

This will (proportionally) scale down any over-wide images so that they'll fit within the column.

Of course, in the mean time, the obvious work-around is to avoid using any images wider than 411px (the width of the "about me" column) in your profile.  One thing that makes this a bit more difficult is that the preview shown when you *edit* your profile is significantly wider, making it hard to judge what the final result will look like.  Still, as long as you know what the limit is, you can size your images accordingly.

(The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25052) linked by DavidPostill in the comments gives a few useful tips for resizing your images.  In particular, for images hosted on imgur, inserting the letter `m` just before the filename suffix will automatically resize the image to 320px wide.)