# Sorting questions requires page refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web, sorting

I was viewing my profile through the browser (Chrome for Android) and I noticed the mobile site did not auto refresh the posts when I sorted them, I had to refresh manually. The screenshots below should clarify what I mean.

**Before Sort**

[image]

**After Choosing Sort Type**

I went back to check if it had selected *Newest* which it had as the image shows,

[image]

however it hadn't updated.

**Post Refresh**

After refreshing the page it had updated to show the sorted answers.

[image]

Since the full site obviously showing the list with the new sort without reloading, this should be the same in the mobile theme as well.

It would definitely increase the user friendliness.

Comment: @Paweł thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard how did you make the images smaller in the question?

Comment: I added the letter "l" after the image name. imgur is generating several sizes when uploading images. More details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post)

Comment: @Paweł I noticed the review tag, just in case you forgot about it, reminding you. :)

Comment: No worries, I keep it in back of my head. It just needs slightly more time than simple CSS fix.

Comment: @Paweł heh, someone else stole your bug fix! :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mobile html was missing some classes expected by the javascript. Fixed rolling out with next build (rev `2016.8.30.4932` on MSE/MSO, `2016.8.30.3935` on sites).

Comment: Looks like Mr. Paweł  was working on the bug, did he ask for help? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can neither confirm nor deny