# Sizing suffixes on uploads broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, imgur, image-size-modifiers

Traditionally [we could easily resize an image by adding a s,m or l](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25052/135565) at the end of a filename after uploading it via the image uploader. That doesn't seem to work any more. I've tested it on Q&A as well as chat.

> [image]

(Yes, I know big M doesn't work)

Could we have this fixed please?

Comment: I believe the query string modifications have been on-and-off broken today too (people's profile pictures weren't loading). Imgur has been having a lot of problems today. But they usually get fixed with time.

Comment: I was slightly iffy about posting it here cause its clearly an imgur error,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report, I have raised this issue with Imgur.  They have been upgrading our hosted image service so this is probably something simple that was missed during the upgrade.  It should be fixed shortly.

Comment: Looks like it works at the moment.

Comment: Geoff any chance imgur "forgot" to fix the 96x96 thumbnail? See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302020/cropped-avatar-is-shown-in-full-but-distorted-in-the-users-page) for context.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @ShadowWizard

Comment: As it's currently broken again – so can you please re-raise the issue with Imgur?

Comment: @Izzy all appears to work here.  Do you have a specific example?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Just picked the [first post I could find](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201821/16575) with big images, and adding the `m` suffix doesn't resize any of them, neither does `t` (while `s` and `b` work). Picture to play with: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/FygrS.jpg`.