# Search is incorrectly adding tags to search criteria

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This search should not be searching in any tags:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=select+wpf+tabitem

But it "helpfully" adds the [wpf] tag to my search criteria.

I can't seem to get it to f**k-off-and-do-what-I-say, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=select+%22wpf%22+tabitem

Enclose the search term that's turning into a tag in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The top (n) tags in the tag list are automatically turned into tags when they appear in searches.

This is because we had so many users (and still do) who love to type things like "C#" in the search box.

Comment: Ah, well, that makes sense.  I didn't realize that [WPF] was in the top (n).  I think that the search hints should be a little bit more helpful for this circumstance, tho.

Comment: I think it would be good to inform the users of this instead of just doing it silently behind their backs (e.g. adding "you searched for XX but we assume you meant YY (if this is not correct click here to search for XX) somewhere on the search result page).