# Allow turning off search auto-tagging?

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

I wanted to look for a book called [Essential JavaScript And jQuery Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/4539087#4539087) in [List of freely available programming books on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/379641).

I performed the search using [`essential javascript inquestion:194812`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=essential+javascript+inquestion:194812). To my surprise, there was no result returned. I was not aware that the term `javascript` was [turned into tag automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47826/151244) until I read about it.

A friendly way to notify users and/or turn off the auto-tagging in search would be helpful. Possible solution:

- As [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47826/search-is-incorrectly-adding-tags-to-search-criteria/47829#47829) by [hlovdal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133217/hlovdal), a visual notification like "You searched for XX but we assume you meant YY (if this is not correct click here to search for XX)". This would be especially useful and friendly for new users. They would not know how to avoid/remove the autotag by using double quotes until they read this post.
- Another Super Ninja search syntax, like `autotag:0` (this would [add more complexity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10934/151244) though).

Comment: If the user knows to add `autotag:0`, why don't they simply quote those the search terms? `"essential" "javascript" inquestion:194812`

Comment: @KennyTM, that is feasible, but not so friendly. Imagine typing 10 double quotes with five terms. Imagine surrounding every terms with quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by putting a plus in front of the search term, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: Also, quoting does the trick.

Comment: thanks for the "plus" info, but could you elaborate more on why you do not recommend it? Also, my question is aimed to provide a visual cue to users who do not know how to remove/avoid the search auto-tagging (unless they read this post, of course).

Comment: `ping`: any clue as for why putting a plus in front of the search term is not recommended? (Just curious.)

Answer (score 0):

Due to [the changes we made in the search engine recently](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/), this is now easier.  Before the only option was `+term` to avoid it becoming `[term]` (a tag search), now you can do it **without** *requiring* the term by using quotes around a word.  So for example "javascript" would not turn it into a tag search, you can try it here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22javascript%22

---

Or, more relevant to your question, your query would be: **essential "javascript" inquestion:194812**

Try it here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=essential+%22javascript%22+inquestion:194812

Comment: The "surround search terms with double quotes" method was already possible before the recent search engine changes. Please refer to the links in my question and comment by KennyTM. New users would not know about this double quotes method unless they read this post. What I suggested was a more user-friendly way to allow users to turn off auto-tagging (refer to my 1st possible solution). Is that possible?

Comment: @Gan - This actually didn't work in the same way before - it works in all cases now.  I don't agree it's a more user-friendly way of disabling tagging...not that I think either way is especially intuitive.  We're just doing what works for the most users possible to get the results their after.  There are other back-end changes we're making based upon what people are searching for happening as we go.  For example `sql server` will now convert to the `[sql-server]` tag, same with `objective c`, searches we're seeing very common and weren't relevant before (searching for "objective" and "c").

Comment: all in all, this still doesn't solve the user-experience problem stated in the question.

Comment: @Gan - I would argue it *should*, the issue isn't searching, it's mis-tagging on the questions that *aren't* returned, a separate issue we're trying to address through several changes (code highlighting based on tags for example) lately.

Comment: sorry, probably I wasn't clear. I was saying, as at this moment, when new users search for the terms *essential javascript inquestion:194812* (as stated in the question), there is no result, and they would not know they can search *essential "javascript" inquestion:194812* to get the result they want until they read our post here. Note that the question does not have the [javascript] tag. This is what I meant by my previous "still doesn't solve the problem" comment.