# View upvote and downvote totals on Meta?

Tags: support, vote-count

On S[OFU] it's possible to see the total upvotes and downvotes for a given question/answer by clicking on the question score.

[alt text http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/552/votesu.jpg](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/552/votesu.jpg)

Can this be made available on Meta, too?

Comment: Only another 11 up-votes to go :) (as of 2010-06-10 16:44:00Z)

Comment: img 404 ; use imgur

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's already available on Meta, but you need 1000 reputation to see it.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/31491#31491)

Comment: Which, according to his recent Area 51 crusades, should be soon.

Comment: @Gnupi: unless somebody keeps heavily downvoting me like he's presently doing...