# Code should be automatically indented when being written

Tags: feature-request, indentation

Most of the time, I paste example code into my questions/answers, but for very short snippets I also type it directly into the field in the browser. For those times, it would be really nice to have a simple automatic indentation of the code. Nothing fancy that would analyse the presence of opening or closing braces, but some simple mechanism like, e.g., automatically reinsert *n* spaces/tabs after I type Return if the previous line also began with *n* spaces or tabs.

Comment: related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84718/is-there-any-auto-indentation-for-formatted-code/84726#84726

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56326/autoindent-of-source-code

Comment: I'm not asking for full-blown autoindent (which clearly is a huge effort) — just for the reinsertion of whatever my current indentation is on newlines.

Answer (score 2):

Shift-Return already does this, if you can get used to that...

(Or, as a workaround: just type without indenting, then select the whole block, and use the code button or hit Ctrl-K.)

Comment: Shift-Return only inserts 4 spaces. I would like a system that inserts as many spaces as there was on the line before. The workaround is only partially helpful, because if I'm writing a multi-line body of an `if`, I also don't want to indent each line with two/four spaces again.

Comment: Maybe not everyone likes to have code indented that way. It seems like a copy and paste from your favorite editor should take care of that.