# Start new lines of code block with same indent as previous line

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code-block, indentation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Automatic code reindent button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82671/automatic-code-reindent-button)
>   [AutoIndent of Source Code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56326/autoindent-of-source-code)

I realize that you can already indent code blocks with the 'code sample' button or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, but that's something you have to do *after* you've finished writing them. This request is about indenting as you go.

My request is to automatically add the indentation of the previous line after hitting enter. So when typing in the code, the 4 spaces are added automatically for a new line until the code block is ended (by removing them).

It would also be nice if additional indenting is also preserved, for example when the code contains a scope which is indented with extra spaces.