# What does the percentage mean at the privileges page

Tags: support, privileges, privileges-page

At the [Trusted User faq page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) there is a list of all Privileges one can get and how much reputation is required to get that privilege.

At the right side of each privilege, there is a percentage.

> trusted user 2%
>
> ...
>
> retag questions 100%
>
> ...

What does that percentage mean?

Comment: Related: [Privilege pages are confusing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73184/privilege-percentages-are-confusing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's your progress towards earning that privilege.

For retagging questions, you've already reached the required reputation, but for trusted user you only have 2% of the required reputation.

Answer (score 5):

The percentages indicate how close you are, based on reputation, to achieving those privileges. Those at 100% indicate privileges that you've already been granted.