# Thumbnail image on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, images, imgur, image-size-modifiers

How can you thumbnail an uploaded image on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Images embedded in your post are already *displayed* to be 640 pixels wide on the regular site, or 90% on the mobile site, to fit the page layout. If that's not enough, or if you want to reduce the download file size too, you have a couple options:

- Use the [HTML syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) for embedding images, which allows for `height` and `width` parameters. The scaling is done by the browser, and the whole image is still downloaded.
- Create the thumbnail yourself using the image manipulation tool of your choice.
- Invoke [imgur](http://imgur.com/)'s black magic to create the thumbnails for you.

### imgur's thumbnail feature

If you uploaded your image via the editor's upload function, you can let imgur do the work for you. (If they reside on your own imgur account, this will still work, but you really [should use the branded upload](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).)

You do this by [**appending a special suffix** to the image code](https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs).

Consider [this cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCux.jpg). It is too big to fit the page, and its URL is `https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCux.jpg`. With the thumbnail feature, we can do this:

- [/mZCux**s**.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCuxs.jpg) — small square, 90×90 (forced)
- [/mZCux**b**.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCuxb.jpg) — big square, 160×160 (forced)
- [/mZCux**t**.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCuxt.jpg) — small thumbnail, 160×160
- [/mZCux**m**.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCuxm.jpg) — medium thumbnail, 320×320
- [/mZCux**l**.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCuxl.jpg) — large thumbnail, 640×640
- [/mZCux**h**.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCuxh.jpg) — huge thumbnail, 1024×1024

#### Notes

- The square options **s** and **b** will force the image to be a square of that exact size, downscaling/upscaling and cropping it in the process if necessary.
- The thumbnail options won't have any effect if the image is already within the maximum dimensions. They also respect image proportions and won't crop your image.

---

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: PNG seems to work in thumbnails too.

Comment: @3ventic Apparently the rules have changed a bit. Small thumbnails of PNGs are now also PNGs, but different sizes still seem to be converted to JPEG (if resizing is done). Anyway it doesn't really matter because imgur sends the correct `Content-Type` regardless of extension, so I removed that line.

Comment: Help section about images could use this info.

Comment: Cool update. It's worth noting that the default max width of 650 pixels is set for all SE posts. Wider images will get downscaled, losing sharpness. Also, 2 **m**-sized images can fit in a row. I haven't experimented with other sizes, but putting several smaller images in a row allows for neater illustrations.

Comment: Don't forget the `s` parameter for icon sizes. EG: [/mZCux.jpg?s=64](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCux.jpg?s=64).  Valid values for `s` seem to be 16, 32, 64, and 128.

Answer (score 10):

There now is a script that aids you in creating thumbnails:

[Thumbnail Uploader](https://stackapps.com/q/3507)

It adds an improved "upload" dialog:

[image: enter link description here]

The large/medium/small options use the imgur hacks described [above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108821/178438). The height/width creates an HTML image tag (leaving one blank locks aspect ratio).

And, of course, there's a "link to full size" option for thumbnailing.

Comment: Nice! Any chance it can also [ask for a title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88756/can-we-get-rid-of-the-default-text-enter-image-description-here)?

Comment: @Arjan: Yeah, I remember keeping a placeholder for the title in the script, so adding this shouldn't be hard. I'll look into it later. re:HTML _fixed_, thanks :)

Comment: The linked app says it is no longer being maintained.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro The SE uploader design changed so I assume this stopped working as well.