# How can I scale or reduce size of an Image in a post?

Tags: support, images

I recently created [this question on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/177152/43105) and I wonder how can I make the image smaller, because it's too big. The image is added via URL.

I tried using `kbd` but it maintains it's size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's uploaded via imgur, it is as simple as adding "s", "m" or "l" to the image name.

So https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzgWd.png becomes https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzgWdl.png and is scaled down nicely.

Not enough rep in arqade to edit so leaving it to  you. :)

More details in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108821/152859).

Comment: Worken like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: This degrades the quality though: it doesn't produce Retina images.

Comment: @orome that's totally imgur issue, SE can't do anything about it.

Comment: Yes, but that means the imgur solution is of limited value.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the image in the anchor tag after uploading it on SO. use this line:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzgWd.png" height="230"/>
```

Give the height and width of image and you will be able to resize the image.
Cheers.

Comment: Note that while this is a bit unsatisfying from a UX point of view, this approach (as opposed to the [imgur tagging approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236670/164163)) will [also preserve image quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303037/how-do-i-scale-inserted-images).