# How do I scale inserted images without losing quality?

Tags: feature-request, support, images, retina

Is there a way to insert scaled high quality images other than entering HTML directly? I [understand that I can use imgur to size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108821/164163) the displayed image without using HTML, but this produces a degraded non-Retina image.

Comment: I'm afraid there's way using existing SE features/tools. You'll have to do that yourself, and link to the scaled image yourself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: So HTML is still the "state of the art", as it were.

Comment: More like non-elegant workaround, but yeah, nothing changed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Too bad. Well, at least I haven't failed to used some new feature!

Comment: Kinda curious where this would be useful - SE isn't HiDPI/Retina friendly anyway, and dem filesizes.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I'm not sure what you mean. It's useful for anyone looking at the image. Most screenshots (*all* on iOS or macOS) generate images that are too large for comfort in SE posts so they need to be scaled down. And scaling them without making them into low-quality blurs should be useful for anyone. And what do you mean by SE not being HiDPI/Retina friendly? Some considerable effort was undertaken a while back to update all graphics on all SE sites to HiDPI/Retina.

Comment: I run a 4k screen (x2) and just resize prior to uploading. Works ok. Stuff like uploads seems designed for sensible file sizes over quality tho

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Yes, resizing prior to uploading is of course the other option. But the question is about whether there is support on this end.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek actually SE spent lots of efforts to support retina display, e.g. creating SVG icons for everything instead of .png they had before. Also worth reading the [full retina support request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161373/hdpi-version-of-stack-exchange).

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes, exactly.