# Is there a way to specify dimensions for an image?

Tags: support, design, images

While uploading an image to a post is there a way to specify the image dimensions?

In SE sites the images uploaded to a post are made to fit the width of the post section, but some of the images are portrait mode, like screenshots of mobile devices like the following image.

[image: Example]

The above image takes lots of vertical space. So is there a way to reduce the size by percentage or exact height and width?

**NOTE**: For editors please don't change the image with edited image which has reduced dimensions.

Comment: Not directly via the uploader, but there are ways to reduce the size as [explained in the answers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: Related: [Thumbnail image on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74312/162827)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the thumbnail resizing from imgur, appending the letter here to the jpg name:

> t Small Thumbnail 160x160
>
> m Medium Thumbnail    320x320
>
> l  Large Thumbnail 640x640
>
> h  Huge Thumbnail  1024x1024

This keeps your image proportions, so if you want it smaller:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cyRIqGTl.jpg]

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWRSSl.jpg
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cyRIqGTm.jpg]

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWRSSm.jpg
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cyRIqGTt.jpg]

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWRSSt.jpg
```

Answer (score 8):

Clunky, but works: Change the image markdown specification to an HTML `<img>` tag with the URL of the image you uploaded, and add the `height` property. E.g., for your image:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/cyRIqGT.jpg" height="450" />
```

Which will give the following image in your case:

[image]

**EDIT:**

As @grgarside suggested in the comments, specifying the width instead of the height would have better effect when rendering on mobile devices. E.g.:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/cyRIqGT.jpg" width="280" />
```

[image]

Comment: Tip: use `width="value"` instead of height to avoid awful stretching on mobile. The mobile CSS sets the max-width, so defining the height too stretches the image, whereas setting the width allows for scaling the image whilst retaining the aspect ratio on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @grgarside! edited it in.