# Merge [code-first] into [ef-code-first]?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Currently [code-first](/questions/tagged/code-first) tag is significantly more popular (129) then [ef-code-first](/questions/tagged/ef-code-first) (38) but I'm sure that [ef-code-first](/questions/tagged/ef-code-first) is much more correct.

What about merge?

Comment: and don't forget `codefirst`, that have only 5 questions but it is the only one with tag wiki. BTW, are you familiar with [tag links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/78346#78346)?