# How do I find out why I lost reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation

I have lost a couple of points today, no biggy, but I can't work out why. Everything points to these pages, but there are no down votes.

[Nodejs output -Domain name not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829511/nodejs-output-domain-name-not-found/5849516#5849516)

[Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript/4258535#4258535)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downvoting an answer "cost" one reputation point. If you downvoted those two answers, it means you lost 2 reputation points because of that.

By the way, downvoting a question is free of any cost.

Comment: Cheers, this is the only reputation loss that is not displayed anywhere.

Comment: You should be able to see the unique IDs of answers you've downvoted in the [Reputation Calculator](http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation) with a `-1` next to them. If you then paste that unique reference number xxx into the URL `stackoverflow.com/questions/xxx` and browse there, you will be navigated directly to the answer you downvoted.

Comment: @raz - nice, didn't know that! This surely worth mentioning here then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow will you pick the glove up, or prefer me to do that? :)

Comment: When you give a downvote, the -1 appears in your reputation summary on your reputation page, with [-1] [downvote] [link to answer].  I don't understand why all of these workarounds are necessary to see this?

Comment: @static weird, I was sure they removed this feature from the reputation page. Anyhow, seeing it all at once in `/reputation` page can still be useful, you don't have to expand anything to find it.

Comment: I agree with that, I was just confused as to why the reputation tab was being ignored in the discussion.

Comment: Hah - didn't know that appeared in the rep page, and have long been using the workaround. :) @static thanks for educating me.

Comment: @static - picky of me, but ones own downvotes actually appear with [downvoted][link to answer]. [downvote] is used to indcate where you have been downvoted by someone else.

Comment: @razlebe, you are correct. I would rather you were picky and the correct information was displayed than you weren't and people saw the wrong information.

Comment: I've added an explanation of that browsing to that "Hidden Features of SO" question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/103685#103685).

Comment: Can I now delete my question to get my meta points back?

Comment: I prefer to avoid deleting questions if they have any value to other people.. points should now not be a problem so I'll advice to keep this question.