# Make all the links in user profile page reachable with keyboard only

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accessibility, tab-key

Sometimes I love to put my mouse away, let it rest, and navigate the site only with keyboard.

With enough <kbd>TAB</kbd> clicks I can reach any link and activate it - all good.

However, in the user profile page there is inconsistency - I can reach all the links, except two: the *visited* that open the calendar with visited days, and the *recent names* link that opens the box with recently used display names.

Quick check revealed both use `<span>` instead of `<a href="#">` like other links that invoke JavaScript action, for example *my logins*.

Can those two become consistent with the other links, or alternatively being assigned some keyboard shortcut?

Comment: This is unrelated to the question, but nice to know: you can navigate using Ctrl-F? Just search for the link and then press Esc followed by Enter. Also, on Firefox, `'` (apostrophe key)  lets you *only* search links and follow them directly with enter. When I learned this, my life became much better :)

Comment: @Tikhon thanks, using Chrome here and no, it didn't work..

Comment: I suspect it's for the same reason as the `tab` stuff. I was mostly just sharing something that took me much too long to find myself.

Comment: Also, I never knew about the calendar. The fact that the number is clickable should be more evident in the UI.

Comment: @Tikhon cheers, it's always good to find hidden treasures. As for making it evident what you suggest? There is handpoint icon when hovering, this is usually enough. :)

Comment: I only noticed the hand after reading your question. I guess I never had any reason to mouse over that bit of the screen (I also use the keyboard a lot). And I spend a lot of time on SO. Probably too much, lately :)

Comment: @Tikhon SO is full with those hidden gems.. there is even [whole "thread" here on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow) that try to collect them all. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Have you ever heard of Vimperator and the like?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft nope, what is this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: A plugin that aims at making Firexfox entirely operable from the keyboard with Vim-like shortcuts, but the Internet can probably explain this better than me. If you don’t like Vim or Firefox, there exist several comparable plugins and similar.