# Improve tab accessibility on login page

Tags: bug, status-deferred, login, accessibility

My trackpad recently ran out of batteries and rather than replacing them I decided to see if I could get by without it.  It is an interesting experiment.

One issue I ran into is that on your login page the buttons for logging in with Google and Facebook do not have a tabindex associated with them and use html span tags so there is no way to click the "Log in using Google" button on this page using only your keyboard.

I was able to get around with it by viewing the source of the page then pasting this into the javascript console

```
$('span', $('.google-login')).click()
```

There is no way someone who is not a developer would know to do that though.

I think it probably makes more sense to make these html `<button>` or `<a>` tags and then the browser should take this into account automatically.

That should improve this page's accessibility.

Comment: This might improve non GUI browsers too - although I don't know

Comment: Highly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119436/make-all-the-links-in-user-profile-page-reachable-with-keyboard-only (and utterly ignored...)

Comment: Yeah, that definitely needs some love. If you tab long enough you can even get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oVrqC.png

Comment: ... but, the thing is, we're completely redoing login (again). I'll make sure to forward the accessibility concerns to the right people.