# Does the /reputation page still need a Trigger Recalc button now that reputation skew is a thing of the past?

Tags: discussion, reputation-recalc

I observe the [reputation recap page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) still features a `Trigger Reputation Recalc` button.

Truth be told, I've been using that button on a quasi-weekly basis for more than a year now, but if I understood [this awesome and prominently featured post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) correctly, it does not serve any purpose anymore (and my first question on meta is answered once and for all).

So, is there any reason for this button to stay, as its use will arguably only trigger superfluous requests to the servers?

*`Bump:`* So, six months later now, may I ask how the reputation view update is coming up? Will we have access to more data? Will the `Recalc` button stay?

Comment: Exactly - its only purpose now is for us to bother the servers with :)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `/reputation` met an untimely end altogether...although if that's the case it'd be nice if days > 200 and such information was presented somewhere...

Comment: Hmm. That actually shows me as having 18,478 reputation, but I only have 18,477 displayed on Meta. Maybe it has a purpose after all? :-)

Comment: Also related, see Nick's comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124059/153008).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are going to remove the button eventually, but the page will still always exist so users can get the full itemized list of everything that's happened on their account.

Quote from [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes/124059#comment328928_123319):

> we don't plan to remove it, but it may get an update to provide a bit more data...right now that mechanism still wouldn't show post deletion for example (no plans to update it at this time though).

Answer (score 4):

The rep recalc button is now gone. In [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43005/237685) answer it states:

> As of December 2013, there is no "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button
>   anymore. Recalc is performed automatically only, in case of reputation
>   inconsistency that does not resolve itself please file a new bug
>   report.

Also, Animuson points out that [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212622/what-happened-to-my-reputation-dropped-about-1500-points?lq=1#comment684600_212622) comment by Nick says:

> @Amicable hitting that button only serves to severely hinder debugging or make it impossible - **it will be removed on the next build**.

Comment: [*"hitting that button only serves to severely hinder debugging or make it impossible - it will be removed on the next build."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212622/what-happened-to-my-reputation-dropped-about-1500-points?lq=1#comment684600_212622)

Comment: @animuson Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I edited that in.