# Are self-triggered reputation recalculations still needed?

Tags: discussion, reputation-recalc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Does the /reputation page still need a Trigger Recalc button now that reputation skew is a thing of the past?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124330/does-the-reputation-page-still-need-a-trigger-recalc-button-now-that-reputation)

Since quite a lot of things have [changed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) during the last period, self triggered reputation recalculations<sup>1</sup> are no longer needed. Shouldn't they be removed from the sites?

<sup>1. self triggered reputation recalculations are triggered by going to `http://[stackexchangesite].com/reputation` and pressing the button at the bottom of the page</sup>

Comment: Needed? No. Removed? No. Let it stay, just in case. You know. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Dear Lord, your gravatar! It's, it's... No words can describe its awesomeness.

Comment: Yeah, my baby daughter riding towards the rainbow on the back of a unicorn.. my skills at photo editing are almost non existent glad you liked it though. ;)

Comment: Who needs photo editing skills when you have unicorns...

Answer (score 9):

According to Nick Craver's comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes#comment331489_124059), the self-triggered recalculations are slated to go, but they are kept around for a while until the team is confident that no glitches have slipped through.

Comment: Yep, a few more *crazy* edge cases are around, (e.g. at this moment 58 of 1.6 million users are out of sync, so not bad at all), we're working through them.

Comment: Hey, 0.003625% is _awesome_.