# What happened to my reputation (dropped about 1500 points)?

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow, reputation

About an hour or so ago, my stack overflow reputation dropped from well over 1000 to just 41. What's going on?

At the same time, my username got reset to one of those numeric ones (user123456 or similar), though I've changed that back to "tobyink" now.

My account is [tobyink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990570/tobyink) - you can see the history is fine, so it's not like I accidentally signed in with a different Open ID and ended up creating a new user with lower reputation.

Comment: Try triggering a recalc from [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: Good to hear! :) I do wonder what caused this though!

Comment: Sounds like the same thing that happened to someone else just a few days ago. But I still can't find the duplicate.

Comment: Naughty pixies.

Comment: Maybe your account was accidentally merged with someone else's? And then later the merge was undone?

Comment: @S.L.Barth - I see no evidence of that in the user record, or any other kind of vote invalidation. Everything looks clean.

Comment: This is really strange, there's no event recorded in your account that would explain this. Looking deeper ...

Comment: @Amicable hitting that button only serves to severely hinder debugging or make it impossible - it will be removed on the next build.

Comment: This [has been reproduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213000/what-happened-to-this-users-rep-and-badges) voting to reopen

Comment: This happened to me too.

Comment: @RichardTingle not debating that this is an issue, but given that we already have a question for this specific bug, do we really need to reopen it and have multiple posts?  It would be better to just ask a mod to rclose this as a dup of the newer question

Comment: @psubsee ideally one would be reclosed as a duplicate of the other. Which seems to have happened so I'm happy