# Why one user with 200+ on questions has still low reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm suprised that this guy, [user2464827](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986493/user2464827), who asked a question about HTML/CSS yesterday, get 152 *+1* on his question and still have only 11 of reputation on StackOverflow: 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986493/user2464827?tab=summary

According to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), each vote up on a question rewards the author with 5 of reputation. Why does this user doesn't have at least 200 of reputation (with the fact that you can't gain more than 200 of rep per day)?

[image: Screenshot of user2464827 profile page]

Did I missed something, a specificity that blocks the reward?

Thanks,

Comment: his [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20728150/1671639) doesn't show any effort but how this gain 100+ votes(that to within a day).

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan Because it's something unsual and not a boring question about syntax. People like the idea I guess.

Comment: The [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2986493/user2464827?tab=reputation) of his profile has him with over 400 rep.  My guess is he just needs a recalc.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan not relevant. He's still getting 200 rep every day for it. There is ongoing bug on Stack Overflow that eats users' reputation, now that there's no way to manually do recalc it's going to spread. :/

Comment: Put up a bounty on the [What happened to this user's rep and badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213000/what-happened-to-this-users-rep-and-badges) question. Marked this as duplicate though.

Comment: @Servy no recalc anymore, they removed the button from the [reputation audit page](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: @Servy - the recalc has been disabled as running it was masking the bug causing this. We need to be able to actually see the data without a recalc hiding all the data.

Comment: @Oded any chance for response on the other question, even just a comment saying "we're looking into it"?