# My user name changed to `userXXXXX`

Tags: bug, display-names

I just noticed that my user name is no longer then same,

As recently as a few months ago, my user name was bonaca, but now it is user182196.

Because I can't see my user name in the new topbar anymore, I'm not exactly sure when it was changed.  What is causing this and what should I do?

Comment: That's no bug. We have a new top-bar. The Stack Exchange Super Duper Multi-Collider (TM).

Comment: @juergend No. [For some reason his username was changed to the default one on certain sites.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TwmCS.png)

Comment: @juergend, but I can't see the username also if I ask some question ? Other users have their username.

Comment: The user name changing could be related to the same bug that is causing users to temporarily lose rep since their user name also changes.  Is your rep correct?

Comment: @psubsee2003, yes, my rep is correct.

Comment: @bonaca you can see your user name, it is just reset to the default `userXXXXX`. I think the "can't see" part was confusing people, so I edited your question to ask what I think you were trying to ask.  Please feel free to roll back the edit, or edit it further if I am missing anything

Comment: @psubsee2003, yes, that's it. But who changed my username and why?

Comment: @bonaca see the top voted answer, it is a bug.

Comment: @psubsee2003, thanks. Problem seems solved. Please look at `Flyk`'s answer.

Comment: @bonaca by the way, you got a hat!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After discussion in the comments, it seems this is less of a case of you not being able to see your username and that the issue is that your username has changed. To change this back to bonaca, go to your profile page, click edit and change your username there. By the looks of things you problem may be caused by the information shown in [the other answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214618/229699).

Additionally, the top bar was replaced a few months ago and your logged in username is no longer shown in the top bar. Instead, only your avatar, reputation, and current badge count are showed where your username used to be, and clicking on this information will take you to your profile, which will show your username.

For more information, check out the information here -> [New top bar quick reference guide / Where has the link to <X> gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone/210187#210187)

Comment: Flyk, but I can't see the username also if I ask some question ? Other users have their username.

Comment: You can't see your username on *questions*? I can see your username when you make posts. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Flyk, I can also see my username HERE, but not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: On Stack Overflow your username is user182196 - to change this back to bonaca go to your [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/current), click edit and change your username there. By the looks of things you problem may be caused by the information shown in [the other answer to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214618/229699).

Comment: @Flyk you might want to edit your last comment into your answer since the OP seems to be more worried about the fact that his display name changed and how to fix it, not that he actually can't see it.

Answer (score 10):

There is a known bug that is still going on, first reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213000/what-happened-to-this-users-rep-and-badges).

Something is causing the reputation, badges and username to "reset". It appears random, and the developer team is looking into it.

The reputation and badges are recalculated at some point (usually within a day), but the username needs to be changed back manually.

Comment: I upvoted one of the "victims" and that didn't reset anything. They had already hit the rep cap that day though.

Comment: @MartinSmith what user is that?

Comment: [the one discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213423/145673) though of course all resolved now.

Comment: Yeah, remember that one... when did you upvote exactly?

Comment: Probably 5 minutes after that meta question was posted. Can't check exactly from my vote history AFAIK as on Ipad and no mouseover tooltips.

Comment: `2013-12-23 21:22:42Z`. I'm pretty confident that it wasn't resolved before that question got closed 40 minutes later.

Comment: @MartinSmith according to my theory the reset occurred while he was rep capped, then  his rep was recalculated on 2013-12-24 02:37 when he received his next "real" upvote. Can you find way to prove it wrong?

Comment: No. Seems a reasonable assumption to me. Though I have no idea if it is right either! [The user here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213503/145673) got an upvote at`10:42` on 24 Dec but they didn't comment to say all had fixed itself.

Comment: @MartinSmith yep. You can ask that user how long after he posted his rep was "fixed", note he didn't yet change the display name back.