# See how many duplicates of a post?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, search, duplicate-answers

Can I see how many duplicates there are of a post? I.e. how many posts have been labelled as duplicate because of this post? If so, how? And can I also get a list of these duplicated posts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most reliable way to do this is to [use the Data Explorer:](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162748/duplicates-for-a-given-post?OriginalPostId=8028957)

```sql
select PostId as [Post Link]
from PostLinks
where RelatedPostId=##OriginalPostId##
and LinkTypeId=3 -- duplicate
```

This will give you both a total count for questions closed as duplicates of a given original post, *and* links to all of the ones that haven't been deleted yet.

Comment: What is the lag between the data explorer content and the live content (if any)? Just as a reference.

Comment: Cheers Mr. jon.doe6935, and it even show deleted posts!

Comment: @Werner see [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/help): *The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC*

Comment: I just tested with [`postId=213000`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213000/what-happened-to-this-users-rep-badges-and-name) which does have duplicate posts, but turns out nothing. What did I miss?

Comment: @herohuyongtao works for me.  You probably forgot to switch sites.  The query Shog references defaults to SO.  You have to click on the MSO icon next to "switch sites" under the Run Query" button to get it to search the MSO database.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Worked now, it has to be switched to SO to search the MSO database. Thanks.

Comment: the query returns nothing  for me e.g., [there are several duplicates for SO/q/13047806 question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/13047806?q=duplicate%3Ayes) but there are no results if I put `13047806` as `OriginalPostId`.

Comment: Only one duplicate of that question right now, @jfsebastian - and that's too new to have made it into the public data yet. Try it again Monday.

Comment: I've spoken too soon. There is indeed only one duplicate of the given question. And it is too new to appear in Data Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a record of all *linked* questions, both linked from the given question to others and vice versa. You can see the full list by directly browsing to this URL: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/[question id]`

For example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/194476

> [image]

Questions marked `[duplicate]` may be duplicates of the question having the ID in the URL.

If you're already in a question page there is "Linked" section when there are any linked posts:

> [image]

And "see more linked questions…" when there are more than 10. (leading to the above page)

Comment: Worth noting: this will also get you all of the questions that are linked manually by someone, not just the duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work. This includes some posts that are duplicates but not of the source post. Linked posts include any posts that reference the source.

Comment: @Robert true, that's why I suggested visiting the page with all linked questions and those marked duplicate can be assumed to be duplicates of the question at hand.

Comment: Since this is being used as a duplicate target, perhaps add a note about ***links in comments*** being one source of "linked", duplicates being the other? Perhaps backed up by the canonical MSO post about it (e.g., the announcement of it by Atwood).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum well I did write "linked from the given question" which means links posted in the question or its comments. Comment with link to other question won't cause the question where the comment was posted to appear in the Linked Questions of the other question, as far as I know. Unless you think it's wrong?