# "View duplicate questions" doesn't show just duplicate questions

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, linked-questions, user-experience

I just tried to delete https://superuser.com/questions/10721/intelligent-file-copy-move-software, but was told:

[image]

When I click **View duplicate questions**, I get sent to https://superuser.com/questions/linked/10721, which lists all *linked* questions, not just duplicates.

Comment: Well, I see it's deleted now...

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Well, I was able to figure it out ;D …but my point remains.

Comment: Well, there is a way to find them as Shog posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217421/152859). Not elegant, but should work in most cases. :)