# Where can I find the duplicate finder tool?

Tags: support, duplicate-suggestions

I been looking and can’t find the duplicate GUI or search bar to start using it. Do I need to be a certain reputation to access it?

I don’t see it in a google search a ask question search and it gives you related titles.

I’ve also looked in [Are there examples of searching better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369300/1059647) under the comments and related questions and can’t find it.

Any direction would be fine

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217421/259608) fit the bill, or is it something specific I've not heard of that you're after?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBexD.png and this https://i.stack.imgur.com/94XzK.png

Comment: To get it to work properly can be tricky. Typing your exact title finds no results, but [deleting a word from the beginning and end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEBkR.png) at least finds something; removing other random words either improves or gives too many results. It could certainly use some improvement, rarely it works very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've been able to dig up some very old screenshots, well done :) It looks a bit different now, but it's still found in the same place. It is part of the 'flag dialog': under each post, there's a list of links, and 'Flag' is one of them:

[image]

Choose 'a duplicate' (of course, this option is only available for questions, not for answers):

[image]

But, to be honest, this duplicate finder is not really good at finding duplicates. I always use the [regular search](/search) and Google or other search engines are even better (or so I heard). I see now you received some suggestions already in the comments to [your earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369300/295232).

> Do I need to be a certain reputation to access it?

Yes, [flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) requires 15 reputation, so you'd be able access it here, and on Photography Stack Exchange. You *don't* need to have the privilege to [cast close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), but if you do, you can also reach the duplicate finder via the 'Close' link.

Comment: I think I’m gonna take the approach from daily living and finding new things by tapping or pressing every button to see what it does so I’m familiar with it. I would have never thought or used the flag button to find a tool. Should have seen it

Comment: Curiosity will get the best of you! Another tip: *hover* over certain UI elements (e.g. those post menu links, or timestamps such as the x mins ago under this post).

Comment: I’m on mobile 100% of the time I can’t hover over anything. I use the responsive website. I gotta poke around  I can’t take you for some reason @Glorfindel something is up

Comment: @Glorfindel many of my question are closed as duplicate. So can you help me how can I find duplicate of question. MSE search isn't too good to find duplicate

Comment: @JitendraSingh you could have a look at the comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369300/295232) as well. Also, it gets better the more you practice. Don't worry, you'll get there... I still use MSE search, mainly because tag filtering works quite well once you know which tags to use.