# How much effort was required to develop Unicoin?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, unicoins

I wondered a lot when I saw the Unicoin April fool yesterday. Since, in my experience, development takes a great time.

Is it possible to have some information about the effort which this development required?

Answer (score 41):

It took 6-8 weeks.

(Jokes aside, it took a few weeks of work<sup>1</sup> by [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) -- he will answer separately if he has time)

<sup><sup>1</sup> The spec is dated 10 March, 19:45</sup>

---

Original answer:

A little known fact is that in the stack overflow code base, there are exactly:

- 37 usages of the F-word
- 37 usages of the S-word
- 60 mentions of unicorns
- one usage of "giant S"
- one mention of ponies
- 5 mentions of waffles

How many can you find in our publicly accessible files?

Comment: THIS.  Was worth all of the April 1 madness.

Comment: [This must be one of those 37 instances.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hsg7j.png) (From here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217031/169611)

Comment: congrats on your first reversal badge on meta!

Comment: ... you're going to post all of these occurences for our viewing pleasure, right?

Comment: Coding lessons shall be profferred at Central Park.

Comment: SE has publicly accessible code? Linky plz!

Comment: @Undo That would kinda spoil the fun of "How many can you *find*" if all you have to do is Ctrl-F.

Comment: @undo, think... Not all code is c#, not all files are code... :-)

Comment: And how many mentions of waffles?

Comment: @Sklivvz And dev sites surely are easier to dig through! :P Found one already...

Comment: @ninjalj 5 mentions of waffles

Comment: @Undo there is the `formatUnicorn` function in the javascript. Rather useful one, does string substitution. +1 would unicorn again.

Comment: Found most occurrences in public code: http://pastebin.com/GxFSS8V7

Comment: Uh, @Sklivvz, why does [review.js](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/review.en.js?v=94142e8b25e0) create its own `JSON` function?

Comment: @Manishearth you forgot that there's also javascript embedded in html pages, some occurrences are there.

Comment: Hm, good point. I want pull access -_-

Comment: **Few weeks** of work on a single-day-no-real-use prank? Wow. Kudos to SE!

Comment: Also, will balpha be paid with unicoins this month? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Don't think of it as one day. Think of it as months and months of productivity wasted by clicking rocks.

Comment: Will unicoins be back next year?

Comment: @gitsitgo next year I doubt it, but since unicorns were already in the past, they might come back at some form within 2-3 years. :-)

Comment: I assume the f word is filly, and the s word is sire.