# Gained 137K rep overnight

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, network-profile, combined-flair

It looks like flair data has some issues, here are screenshots from my Wordpress.com blog and profile pages. As you can see I have ~1K rep on the Server Fault, but flair thinks that I have 137K more:

---

[image: Wordpress.com] [image: Flair]

---

[image: Profile]

---

[image: Top]

---

Comment: Well, that's certainly... an odd bug.

Comment: Looks like you got mixed up with SF top user, http://serverfault.com/users/13325

Comment: You must have been working really hard :D

Comment: Well, congratulations, I guess. :)

Comment: I blame Robin Hood. I knew it was just a matter of time before that scoundrel turned to rep.

Comment: A fix is incoming, I'll post details here in a bit.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So like most things in life, this was my fault. Historically we had 2 systems for getting data and never really finished moving to the latter. One of those artifacts came up with some Developer Timeline work that showed us doing an unnecessary HTTP request to the 2.0 API to get your user list for the Communities section of the profile. There's no need for that overhead, we've got database access.

We also didn't need to cache the number of strings returned with a `!8.(3p54UxIbJyv5MuonC6aUPxvldcj7CbjQXT8` filter, since we have the sites readily available in local cache all we needed was an integer. So we could save time, an HTTP request, deserialization time, allocations, redis wire time, and memory all by switching over to a faster database query.

Paired with this was code cleanup: moving these methods from `User` since "getting other network users" didn't really belong there, to `Account`. That's where this line of code didn't get changed:

```
Hooks.UserReputationChanged(Id, user.Reputation, Current.Site.Id);
```

It should have been:

```
Hooks.UserReputationChanged(user.Id, user.Reputation, Current.Site.Id);
```

So...my bad. It should be fixed as cache expires since the place this happens is in the correction logic. This section of code was written to sync up what you see with what is returned. Since the network-wide aggregation can lag up to a second we need to replace the current-site data in the return set to match your top bar so it appears in sync. If a difference is detected, we also issue an aggregator request to fix it...just in case. That's the code that was getting hit here.

If anyone has more questions I can clarify a bit, I just thought some background on how this works may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it was fun while it lasted :).

Comment: Why weren't other accounts affected though? I've checked http://serverfault.com/users/1000/kris and http://stackexchange.com/users/1000/dan-blair a few hours ago and there was no problem with their flairs.

Comment: @nicael because only hitting an aggregator skew on a cache miss (both very unlikely) would trigger the condition

Comment: @nicael Well, I personally enjoyed being a chosen one :)

Comment: @beatcracker It's okay, [ewwhite](http://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite) would have caught up with you [pretty quickly](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/2/year/serverfault).

Answer (score 21):

I found a pretty strange coincidence, after having seen @Sha's comment. The network-wide profile of ewwhite has this link:

```
http://stackexchange.com/users/270504/ewwhite
```

And yours Server Fault profile has the same id:

```
http://serverfault.com/users/270504/beatcracker
```

This is weird, but could be the reason (and probably someone's else has been also affected).

Comment: Huh! Excellent detective work!

Comment: Nice find. :) I guess...

Comment: Not only flair, it also shows the borked rep in his MSE profile: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vUHWy.png.

Comment: @Sha Yup, noticed, I believe it's just a consequence.

Comment: IMO there is some global repository for cached reputation, used both for global flair and the per-site "Communities" mini list reputation, and when it was updated, there was some mixup

Comment: Anyway, this reminds me of the rep eating worm (not you, @nic ;)) just the opposite - you was around when that super bug hit?

Comment: @Sha Nope, or at least I don't recall.  Does it have a dedicated question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213000/what-happened-to-this-users-rep-badges-and-name

Comment: @Sha Ah, seen this :)