# Accepted answer date and time not being updated when it was previously accepted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

This is something I noticed:

As per my rep records, I just lost 15 rep as an unaccept:

[image]

When I went over to the answer, the timestamp on the now-accepted answer made no sense:

[image]

How is that an answer which was accepted 2 years ago, made me lose rep now?

Looking at the [timeline](https://superuser.com/posts/47098/timeline), I think this is what has happened:

[image]

- Ganesh's answer was initially accepted.
- In December, my answer was marked as accepted.
- Today, my answer was marked as unaccepted.

So, does this mean that unaccepting my answer resulted in the previous marked as accepted answer being marked as the-current-accepted-answer, even though the *timeline* doesn't explicitly say it has been accepted?

Or is that the timestamp on the once-accepted-answer isn't updated?

Comment: I did NOT even know that `/timeline/` existed. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @Manishearth, then [enjoy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: Awesome post, _Bookmarked_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when a question is merged.  For accepted answers **THERE CAN BE ONLY ONE**, so the earliest wins.  You can see that a merge happened here: https://superuser.com/posts/59860/revisions

Kudos to [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) for finding that, I thought we had a phantom double accept cleanup job I was incapable of finding and was going slightly mad.

Comment: Aha, so my answer was accepted on the previous question, the merge meant the question had 2 accepts, so my answer was unaccepted?

Comment: @Sathya - yup, exactly

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clearing that up!