# What is http://stackoverflow.com/reputation?

Tags: discussion, support

Accidentally I got the url https://stackoverflow.com/reputation .
It is giving some statistics about my details.
What is this? I didn't see this url in anywhere in SO.

Comment: It's your reputation audit page.

Comment: The answer is in the duplicate @Bart found, but keep in mind that auditing your reputation is not necessary any more. In the old days, reputation updates were not live, and you had to recalc manually every now and then. `/reputation` is just a relic nowadays, and the only thing useful in there is the information at the bottom.

Comment: You can see this and many more "hidden" links and features here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/152859