# Question page activity history

Tags: support

Is there a way to see the full history of a question's activity, with all comments, answers and edits sorted by the time they took place?

Some questions become so hot it's hard to follow all the changes, and sometimes a comment or an edit gets overlooked.

Comment: [Like this one?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/176906/timeline)

Comment: Exactly! How do I access it?

Comment: You can see this and many more neat tricks [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/152859).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called **timeline**.

You can see the activity of the question by timeline. You can see any question's timeline by adding `/timeline` after the question's id in the URL. Here you need to remove question title first.

Like this:

[`https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/176906/timeline`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/176906/timeline)

There is a userscript to add *timeline* and *revision* link next to *flag* link.

[Add Timeline and Revisions Links](https://stackapps.com/q/2371/11265)

Comment: I wonder why there is no such button, especially near the `asked, viewed, active` gadget.

Comment: @user1306322 - Because it's a [hidden feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/152859).

Comment: Well, I just knew it had to be there with all the other useful stuff. Thanks!

Comment: The link has to have `/posts/` instead of `/questions/` in order for this to work.