# Viewing another user's privileges shows my reputation instead of theirs

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, users

At the right hand side, where it indicates what the next privilege to unlock is, the progress bar uses *my* current reputation rather than the reputation of the user I'm currently viewing privileges for.

> [image: ummm, okay?]

I first noticed this viewing a user's privileges from the moderator tools, but experimenting on another site, it appears you can actually append `/user/<id>` to the end of the privileges page URL and see any other user's privileges without any special permission.

The actual *list* of privileges at the left is correctly displayed for the user you're viewing, but not the bar at the right.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a new hidden feature.

Comment: Looking into that

Comment: @hims056 Not hidden, mods have a direct link to it :P

Comment: +1 for freehand circle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fixed views are live from build 2013.7.10.830 on.

As for the other part of your question, the `/user/<id>` suffix for that route is indeed valid and allowed for everyone to see, since a user's reputation is also visible to everyone. I would say [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) in that regard.