# How does bounty awarded by community to an answer with 1 upvote?

Tags: discussion, bounties

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763216/1341006) to [Android "No content provider found for permission revoke"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550798/android-no-content-provider-found-for-permission-revoke) has one upvote and has 25 bounty awarded by community. What I know is that, community awards bounty only if the answer has 2 or more vote ups, but in this case the vote ups are only 1. How come in this case the bounty is awarded?

Comment: maybe an additional upvote got removed after the bounty was awarded.

Comment: @juergend but voteups are automatically get locked after a period of time?

Comment: Yes, but if a post gets edited a once locked vote can be removed.

Comment: Note that the answer was edited days after the bounty was awarded: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11763216/revisions. After this edit, it is possible to remove an upvote given for a limited amount of time.

Comment: @Haidro: But the answer was edited on [21st Aug](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11763216/revisions). And looking at [his reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/john?tab=reputation&StartDate=2013-08-21) there is no *unupvote* event for that answer after 21st Aug. Probably a curious case.

Comment: @Haidro - The [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11550798/timeline) gives no evidence that this happened though.

Comment: @MartinSmith I never even knew that existed :o

Comment: @Haidro - Then you probably have not visited this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange

Comment: I don't think the timeframe where you can change your vote after an edit is limited. I'm pretty sure I could do it even months after an edit.

Comment: @hims056 That was awesome. Thank you for the link!

Comment: @hims056 very handy link, thank you! There are currently fifty three answers to the question [What are the hidden features of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/303080) :-)

Answer (score 5):

The first count of daily votes in [the answer's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11763216/timeline) is from a few months after the bounty was awarded, and before the first edit.  At that time the question had one upvote, but there's no public data about prior votes.

To get the bounty the answer must have had a second upvote at the time. 
 Because there were no earlier edits, users who upvoted wouldn't have been able to remove those votes.  However, when votes are invalidated or users are deleted, those votes vanish without a trace.  If you've ever lost rep to a "user was removed" event, you know that you don't get told which specific posts were affected.  Unless you happen to notice (for example, you have a Good Answer on something that's now +24/-0), you can't find out.  Even moderators don't have that information.

The most likely explanation is that there was a second vote at the time the bounty ended, and sometime in the next few months that vote was invalidated or the voting user was deleted.