# How to achieve this mirror effect?

Tags: support

In this comment I find it strange that it achieves the mirror effect without affecting the name. How can I do that?

[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment538097_3122)

I know that you can use the Unicode U+202e to achieve the mirror effect, but it still affects the name. I've tried to see the html but it seems it is still the same (i.e using U+202e/ Html 8238).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heh, that's my comment! Look at the source:

[image: source code]

I put a U+202E (right to left override), spelled "Jeff Atwood" backwards, and then used a U+202D (left to right override) to get my username to still show normally.

I posted an example comment right below. The comment's source is:

> left align {U+202E}ngila thgir{U+202D}

Comment: left align ‮ngila thgir‭

Comment: Thanks I have looked at the source before but I didn't notice the second one.

Comment: jus{U+202E}gniyrt{U+202D}

Comment: yeh not working any more. It's confirmed: all fun stuff removed.

Comment: fun still exists! you just have to know ‮kool ot erehw‭

Comment: yes, it can be used for pranks ‮ (2402 ,2 naJ no detsop saw ti ,on) ‭