# Make 'temporarily suspended' link to the associated message for moderators

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, moderator-tools, account-suspension

Currently, a suspension notice looks like so:

> This account is [temporarily suspended](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for $Reason. The suspension period ends in $TimeLeft.

With "temporarily suspended" linking to [the blog post about suspensions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Since moderators should already know how suspensions work and what they're for, could the text instead link to the mod message sent with the suspension when the page is viewed by a moderator? As an alternative, perhaps the reason could link to the message?

Comment: While this would be nice, I'd like to point out [Tim Post's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238887/214632) to my own (almost, but not quite, entirely unrelated) feature request, wherein he says, "We like to put things that behave differently for moderators behind an obvious 'here be mod things' curtain...."

Comment: If you're already in their profile, it's only one click to their whole message and suspension history, and another click from there. I don't think it's really worth the devs special casing just to let mods skip one click.