# Not able to view the Vote count inspite of upvote

Tags: support, voting

I noticed that I received an upvote in this question,but I don't see the upvote count there.This is the question.
[Programming with ADHD](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/13841/programming-with-adhd)

Here are the screenshots
[image]

In my [profile page](http://://productivity.stackexchange.com/users/13296/productiva) you can see that I have upvoted +5 but I cannot see the count of the upvote,

[image]

My question
Is this a bug ? Or is it something that I am misunderstanding ?

*Note: I did not receive a downvote at all.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got a downvote on that question first and then an upvote which make the total post vote count = 0 and your rep = 6.

> [image]

**Since you can't get below 1 rep, the downvote is not noticable in your reputation history.**

Comment: But see my [vote history](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/users/13296/productiva)

Comment: @Computerone In addition, you can't go below 1 rep, so the first downvote didn't affect your rep (1 -> 1).

Comment: Juergen d - `Since you can't get below 1 rep, the downvote is not noticable.` Can you highlight this in your answer ?

Comment: True, the [question timeline](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/posts/13841/timeline) proves there was first a downvote, then an upvote one day later. Took the liberty to add a screenshot to demonstrate. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for pointing it out. I was never aware of that.I looked in everywhere but how did you get to the timeline ?

Comment: @Comp it's undocumented feature, you get to know about them over time. You can learn about many such features [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange) if you want. :)