# Link the title of the linked questions sidebar to the list of linked questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, linked-questions, sidebar

One of the (semi-)hidden features of SE is that you can [view the linked questions for any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/195609#195609) by visiting the URL `http://[site]/questions/linked/[id]` (where `[site]` is the site host name, and `[id]` is the numeric question ID, as shown in the question URL).  For example, [here's the list of questions linked to this one.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/266034/)

This link is normally shown at the bottom of the linked questions sidebar, if there are more linked questions than the sidebar will accommodate.  However, it's *not* shown for most questions, as they don't have enough links to trigger it.

However, the linked questions page actually contains more information than the sidebar (e.g. tags, author, date, question snippet, # of answers, etc.) and, unlike the sidebar, can be sorted in different ways.  Thus, it would sometimes be useful to have easy access to this page even for questions that only have a moderate number of other questions linked to them.  Currently, in the absence of the "see more linked questions..." link, you have to remember the proper URL syntax in order to get to that page.  It would be handy if it was possible to get there with a single click from any question.

Of course, nobody wants to clutter up the interface with unnecessary extra links.  However, there's a natural place where this link could be placed *without adding any extra visual elements to the page:* the title of the sidebar section.

[image: Screenshot with sidebar title highlighted]

The HTML code for the title is currently:

```html
<h4 id="h-linked">Linked</h4>
```

I propose changing it to:

```html
<h4 id="h-linked"><a href="/questions/linked/[id]">Linked</a></h4>
```

and adding (something equivalent to) the following CSS rule:

```css
#h-linked a, #h-linked a:visited { color: inherit }
```

to keep the visual appearance as it is.

This styling would make the link something of a "hidden feature", although it would be somewhat discoverable by the fact that the mouse cursor would change when moved over the title.  It should still be useful to experienced users, who are the ones most likely to have need for this feature, though.

---

Ps. Actually, I was going to add a client-side fix into [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) to insert this link anyway, I just needed something to point the fix description to.  Hence this feature request.  Of course, I'd more more than happy if this actually did get added to the standard SE interface.

---

*Update:* The fix is now in SOUP v1.35.1 (devel), and will be part of the v1.36 stable release when it comes out.

It turns out that I need some more CSS to override all the various funny styles that some SE sites like to apply to links in the sidebar.  Here's the CSS that I'm currently using:

```css
#h-linked a, #h-linked a:visited {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    display: inline;
}
```