# Reputation was not reflect to my account even if I not reached the limit to gain the reputation by edit the post

Tags: discussion, reputation, review, edits, suggested-edits

Today, I have faced the problem as my reputation is not reflected in my account when I edited the post (my total edited post is: 455)

- I have edited 5 questions in the Stack Overflow. All changes were approved as shown in below image.
- I have `downvote` one answer (for this I lose one reputation)
- And, I have gained +10 for my answer where `upvote`.

Yesterday, I have total reputation of `1819`. Today, after all this I have `1828`.

My edited post reputation is not reflect in my account even if I not reached the reputation limit gained by [edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

[image: My Activity Tab]

[image: All Actions - Suggestions Tab]

Comment: But, still I'm not reached the 500 edited posts. Then, who it is possible?

Comment: Is it 1000? Where you see you edited only 455 posts?? It's wrong. Your suggested edits tab show 611 suggestions. So 500 suggestions on non-wiki posts have been approved, giving you 1000 reputation already.

Comment: @Zanna when a post is deleted, the reputation gained from editing it is taken away, so that's not the case here.

Comment: If it so, today, I have edited only 5. 611 - 5 = 606. So, how can I gain reputation yesterday?

Comment: I see [541](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4337436/balagurunathan-marimuthu?tab=activity&sort=revisions) revisions and I'm not going to check which of those were on Community Wiki posts. You've reached the limit today on the 1000 rep you can gain from suggested edits.

Comment: @ShadowWizard can you earn the reputation again if you already reached 1000 and the posts were deleted? Er and straying from the topic, why is the number on the profile so wrong? On Ask Ubuntu on my profile it shows edited 9488, but under the users > top editors (all time) it says 9873 (but I have reason to suspect even that number shows attrition as posts are deleted, because someone who used to have exactly 10000 posts edited there now has 9995)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will look forward to be active in this communities. Cheers :)

Comment: @Zanna yes, if a post where you suggested an approved edit is deleted, you lose 2 points, reducing the total to 998, so next approved edit should give 2. As for misleading number, it's something with deleted posts, or edits to your own posts, not sure.

Comment: Can you access the [`Reputation`](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) URL, in the end of the page you can see the text as `earned # reputation from suggested edits`, this helped to know how much reputation you are earned by suggested edits.

Comment: @Zanna found it! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/posts-edited-count-on-profile-is-way-less-than-my-revsions-count.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Could you please share some other useful links such as [`Reputaion`](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)?

Comment: @Arulkumar OP already did and it's 1000, I said exactly that in the first comment, but it was auto deleted since it also contained link to the dupe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks! I still don't understand why there are 3 different numbers... revisions is 11,103, "posts edited" is 9488, but in the slow-to-update users tab, 9873... maybe I should ask a question about the difference between the latter two

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu sure, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange)

Comment: @Zanna think it's asked already, have to go now so can't search, but feel free to ask and worst case it'll be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you very much. It will help me to understand the SO better. Cheers :)))