# Where (and how) can I post tips & tricks for using Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, tips

I have a tip about using Stack Exchange I want to share. It's just a small tip for adding comments on [iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS), nothing spectacular, but I'm certain there are other users who'll find it useful. I'm hesitating on *where* and *how* to share it.

- It's not an undocumented feature of Stack Exchange, so I can't post it as an answer here: [What are the hidden features of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/295232)
- In the past, people have posted blogs about this. That could be an option, but with only one tip, it's a bit meagre and I like it to be part of the community-controlled content.
- Another option is to post it as a self-answer.

  - It works on the mobile website, but also in the app, so [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) isn't the right choice.
  - I'm sure somebody can come up with an equivalent tip for Android, so that rules out [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).
  - That leaves this site, Meta Stack Exchange, as the only option.

Because there are probably more people who have tips & tricks to share, I'd like the idea of a Community Wiki post à la *[Please share your hidden macOS features or tips and tricks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/400/121968)* on Ask Different. To be honest, that one has grown a bit out of proportion, and I don't expect it to happen for this particular topic. **Do you think this is a good idea, or have I missed something?**

Comment: I probably will regret offering this but did you consider SO Documentation? It seems perfect for this ...

Comment: @rene Documentation is only available for tags with at least 500 questions on Stack Overflow. [stack-exchange] doesn't qualify. But supposing we had it on Meta Stack Exchange, that would have been a good option.

Comment: @Glorfindel I'd expect such to find in the [tag:se-meta-meta] tag wiki FAQ questions. ;-D

Comment: Nobody reads tag wikis [citation-needed], and this is not about how to use *Meta* Stack Exchange, but Stack Exchange as a whole.

Comment: @Glorfindel _"but Stack Exchange as a whole."_ That's why I said _meta-meta_.

Comment: OK. I personally would reserve that for discussing things *specific* to Meta Stack Exchange, but YMMV.

Comment: What is the tip you want to post? Could you make it a Q & A?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, but the A would be too long to post it in this Q, distracting from the main point of the question.