# Why are there non-CW answers under this CW question?

Tags: support, community-wiki

[What are the hidden features of Stack Exchange?](/q/8211)

Since this question is a CW, all answers are supposed to be CW, too. However  it looks like something went wrong [here](/a/8212/350567) and [here](/a/8217/350567).

Why???

Comment: maybe a hint, but those two answers seem migrated, not the others if you check the edit history

Comment: The question is VERY  old, posted back in October 2008. Probably back then, new answers to CW questions were not automatically made into CW. If I'll find some official confirmation for this, will post answer.

Answer (score 6):

First, [one of the answers you mention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/8212#8212) was posted before the question was Community Wiki, so there is no reason for it to become CW. However, the [second answer you mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/8217#8217) was indeed posted **after** the question was already CW, so should have been automatically turned into CW too.

However, in the beginning, new answers to CW questions were not automatically turned into CW themselves, unless there were more than 30 answers, and the answer mentioned here was posted way back in October 2008.

See footnote 3 in the answer to [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts):

> In the past, converting a question to community wiki would not automatically convert the answers, so you may see non-Community Wiki answers to older Community Wiki questions. [...] (Newer answers to these older questions will automatically be Community Wiki.)

Also, as can be seen in the [first revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/11741/1) of that answer:

> Posts enter community wiki mode when:
>
> - The body of the post has been edited by four different people.
> - The post has been edited six times by the original owner.
> - The post's author checks the *community wiki* checkbox when composing the question or answer.
> - The post is edited by its original author, who when doing so opts to check the *community wiki*.
> - The question generates more than 30 answers.  In this case, the question and all answers will enter community mode, as will any future answers.

The only thing which caused answers to become CW automatically back then was having more than 30 answers.

The automatic conversion started around 2009, though it's not documented anywhere.