# Going to /review/user-info of an invalid queue or user ID causes a server error

Tags: bug, review, 500-server-error

I learned that you can [go to `https://[Stack Exchange domain].com/review/user-info/[review queue ID]/[user ID]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214527/1377755) in order to view a users review stats such as their daily, weekly, monthly, and all time review count in a certain queue. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/3/16217248).

However I noted that going to an invalid queue or an invalid user ID ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/user-info/0/0)) causes a server error (Oops! Something Bad Happened!). I would expect this to cause a regular 'Page not found' page instead.

Even though this error does not cause much in terms of loss of functionality, generally speaking, server errors should not happen, so I am reporting this.